# How to urlencode data for curl command?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, scripting, urlencode

I am trying to write a bash script for testing that takes a parameter and sends it through curl to web site.  I need to url encode the value to make sure that special characters are processed properly.  What is the best way to do this?

Here is my basic script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
host=${1:?'bad host'}
value=$2
shift
shift
curl -v -d "param=${value}" http://${host}/somepath $@
```

Comment: See also: [How to decode URL-encoded string in shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6250698/55075) for non-curl solutions.

Comment: See also: [How can I encode and decode percent-encoded strings on the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53770/how-can-i-encode-and-decode-percent-encoded-strings-on-the-command-line)

Comment: see also: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/URL_encoding

Answer (score 651, accepted):

Use `curl --data-urlencode`; from `man curl`:

> This posts data, similar to the other `--data` options with the exception that this performs URL-encoding. To be CGI-compliant, the `<data>` part should begin with a name followed by a separator and a content specification.

Example usage:

```
curl \
    --data-urlencode "paramName=value" \
    --data-urlencode "secondParam=value" \
    http://example.com
```

See [the man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode) for more info.

This requires [curl 7.18.0 or newer (released January 2008)](https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_18_0). Use  `curl -V` to check which version you have.

You can as well encode the [query string](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-G):

```
curl --get \
    --data-urlencode "p1=value 1" \
    --data-urlencode "p2=value 2" \
    http://example.com
    # http://example.com?p1=value%201&p2=value%202
```

Comment: Seems to only work for http POST. Documentation here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode

Comment: @StanJames If you use it like so curl can also do the encoding for a GET request.

`curl -G --data-urlencode "blah=df ssdf sdf" --data-urlencode "blah2=dfsdf sdfsd " http://whatever.com/whatever`

Comment: @kberg actually, this will only work for query data. curl will append a '?' followed by the urlencoded params. If you want to urlencode some  url postfix (such as a CouchDB GET for some document id), then '--data-urlencode' won't work.

Comment: Doesn't work for `curl --data-urlencode "description=![image]($url)" www.example.com`. Any idea why?
`

Comment: I want to URL encode the URL path (which is used as a parameter in a REST API endpoint). There is no query string parameters involved. How do I do this for a GET request?

Comment: It doesn't work for --data-urlencode "key=special "string""
What are we missing here?

Comment: @NadavB Escaping the `"`‽

Comment: Careful with `{}` and `[]` and curl.   Use the `-g` option to turn OFF globbing.

Comment: `-G, --get : Put the post data in the URL and use GET` comment from @kberg works good

Comment: But how about encoding the url itself ? like http://myapi.dev.com/valübülü ?

Comment: Is it possible to make this work with the path instead of the query?

Comment: `-X GET` is not the same as `--get` or `-G` and thus doesn't work. `--get` works great though!

Answer (score 305):

Another option is to use `jq`:

```
$ printf %s 'input text'|jq -sRr @uri
input%20text
$ jq -rn --arg x 'input text' '$x|@uri'
input%20text
```

`-r` (`--raw-output`) outputs the raw contents of strings instead of JSON string literals. `-n` (`--null-input`) doesn't read input from STDIN.

`-R` (`--raw-input`) treats input lines as strings instead of parsing them as JSON, and `-sR` (`--slurp --raw-input`) reads the input into a single string. You can replace `-sRr` with `-Rr` if your input only contains a single line or if you don't want to replace linefeeds with `%0A`:

```
$ printf %s\\n multiple\ lines of\ text|jq -Rr @uri
multiple%20lines
of%20text
$ printf %s\\n multiple\ lines of\ text|jq -sRr @uri
multiple%20lines%0Aof%20text%0A
```

Or this percent-encodes all bytes:

```
xxd -p|tr -d \\n|sed 's/../%&/g'
```

Comment: <3 it ... should be top & accepted IMO  (yeah if you can tell `curl` to encode that works and if bash has a builtin that would have been acceptable - but `jq` seems like a right fit tho i'm far from attaining comfort level with this tool)

Comment: for anyone wondering the same thing as me: `@uri` is not some variable, but a literal jq filter used for formatting strings and escaping; see [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual) for details (sorry, no direct link, need to search for `@uri` on the page...)

Comment: the xxd version is just the kind of thing I was looking for. Even if it's a little dirty, it's short and has no dependencies

Comment: A sample usage of jq to url-encode: `printf "http://localhost:8082/" | jq -sRr '@uri' `

Comment: I think the only reason this isn't the top answer is because OP specifically asked about `curl`. You wouldn't loop in a second tool, `jq`, if curl can do it alone. However, this is _awesome_ general utility to pipe output to, in a script or on the command line.

Comment: Note, this is not suitable for binary data. `jq` can only operate on UTF-8 strings, so binary data which is not invalid UTF will be munged into valid UTF-8 before encoding. To test this, run: `printf '\xAB\xCD\xEF' | jq -sRr @uri`. There is an open PR which may fix this: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/2314

Comment: This really saves the day, thanks. I’d suggest using Bash’s `<<<` (here-string) rather than a cumbersome `printf`. It seems that the final newline does not bother `jq`: `jq -rR @uri <<< 'foo bar'` → `foo%20bar`

Comment: The `echo -n` would also do the trick like:  `echo -n "${TO_ENCODE}" | jq -sRr @uri` .

Comment: Link to manual section explaining `@uri`: https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Formatstringsandescaping

Answer (score 235):

## Here is the pure BASH answer.

**Update**: Since many changes have been discussed, I have placed this on https://github.com/sfinktah/bash/blob/master/rawurlencode.inc.sh for anybody to issue a PR against.

**Note**: This solution is not intended to encode unicode or multi-byte characters - which are quite outside BASH's humble **native** capabilities.  It's only intended to encode symbols that would otherwise ruin argument passing in POST or GET requests, e.g. '&', '=' and so forth.

**Very Important Note**: DO NOT ATTEMPT TO WRITE YOUR OWN UNICODE CONVERSION FUNCTION, IN ANY LANGUAGE, EVER.  See end of answer.

```
rawurlencode() {
  local string="${1}"
  local strlen=${#string}
  local encoded=""
  local pos c o

  for (( pos=0 ; pos<strlen ; pos++ )); do
     c=${string:$pos:1}
     case "$c" in
        [-_.~a-zA-Z0-9] ) o="${c}" ;;
        * )               printf -v o '%%%02x' "'$c"
     esac
     encoded+="${o}"
  done
  echo "${encoded}"    # You can either set a return variable (FASTER) 
  REPLY="${encoded}"   #+or echo the result (EASIER)... or both... :p
}
```

You can use it in two ways:

```
easier:  echo http://url/q?=$( rawurlencode "$args" )
faster:  rawurlencode "$args"; echo http://url/q?${REPLY}
```

[edited]

Here's the matching rawurldecode() function, which - with all modesty - is awesome.

```
# Returns a string in which the sequences with percent (%) signs followed by
# two hex digits have been replaced with literal characters.
rawurldecode() {

  # This is perhaps a risky gambit, but since all escape characters must be
  # encoded, we can replace %NN with \xNN and pass the lot to printf -b, which
  # will decode hex for us

  printf -v REPLY '%b' "${1//%/\\x}" # You can either set a return variable (FASTER)

  echo "${REPLY}"  #+or echo the result (EASIER)... or both... :p
}
```

With the matching set, we can now perform some simple tests:

```
$ diff rawurlencode.inc.sh \
        <( rawurldecode "$( rawurlencode "$( cat rawurlencode.inc.sh )" )" ) \
        && echo Matched

Output: Matched
```

And if you really really feel that you need an external tool (well, it will go a lot faster, and might do binary files and such...)  I found this on my OpenWRT router...

```
replace_value=$(echo $replace_value | sed -f /usr/lib/ddns/url_escape.sed)
```

Where url_escape.sed was a file that contained these rules:

```
# sed url escaping
s:%:%25:g
s: :%20:g
s:<:%3C:g
s:>:%3E:g
s:#:%23:g
s:{:%7B:g
s:}:%7D:g
s:|:%7C:g
s:\\:%5C:g
s:\^:%5E:g
s:~:%7E:g
s:\[:%5B:g
s:\]:%5D:g
s:`:%60:g
s:;:%3B:g
s:/:%2F:g
s:?:%3F:g
s^:^%3A^g
s:@:%40:g
s:=:%3D:g
s:&:%26:g
s:\$:%24:g
s:\!:%21:g
s:\*:%2A:g
```

While it is not impossible to write such a script in BASH (probably using `xxd` and a very lengthy ruleset) capable of handing UTF-8 input, there are faster and more reliable ways.  Attempting to decode UTF-8 into UTF-32 is a non-trivial task to do with accuracy, though very easy to do inaccurately such that you think it works until the day it doesn't.

Even the Unicode Consortium removed their sample code after discovering it was no longer 100% compatible with the actual standard.

The Unicode standard is constantly evolving, and has become extremely nuanced. Any implementation you can whip together will not be properly compliant, and if by some extreme effort you managed it, it wouldn't **stay** compliant.

Comment: The [current version](https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/packages/net/ddns-scripts/files/usr/lib/ddns/url_escape.sed) does not suffer from that bug.

Comment: +1 for the bash implementation of rawurldecode, didn't know printf did %x or -v

Comment: @Pumbaa80 sorry, my fault for still running Backfire 10.03 r20728.  Thanks for editing, I thought I was going to actually have to use my brain for a second :p

Comment: @Pumbaa80: just checked the first edits (rawurldecode), but all tha red and green hurt my thinker - but the version that is up now is 100%.  so if i previously wrote anything different to that, i was high on glue.  thanks for catching it :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this script fails on some characters, such as 'é' and '½', outputting 'e%FFFFFFFFFFFFFFCC' and '%FFFFFFFFFFFFFFC2', respectively (b/c of the per-character loop, I believe).

Comment: @Lübnah: You must be using BASH 3.x, works great in BASH 4.  I don't know an easy way to fix it, i.e. _printf '%%%d' "'é"_

Comment: @Lübnah: sorry, i tried to find an quick fix for BASH 3, but I couldn't.  I'm afraid you'll just have to use a slower method from elsewhere on this page.  Or post a new question, asking for my answer to be made to work with BASH 3 :)

Comment: It fails to work for me in Bash 4.3.11(1).
The string `Jogging «à l'Hèze»` generates `Jogging%20%abà%20l%27Hèze%bb` that cannot be feed to JS `decodeURIComponent` :(

Comment: In that first block of code what does the last parameter to printf mean? That is, why is it double-quote, single-quote, dollar-sign, letter-c, double-quote? Does does the single-quote do?

Comment: @dmcontador - it's only a humble bash script, it has no conception of multi-byte characters, or unicode.  When it see's a character like ń (`\u0144`) it will naively output %144, ╡(`\u2561`) will be output as %2561.  The correct *rawurlencoded* answers for these would be %C5%84%0A and %E2%95%A1 respectively.

Comment: @ColinFraizer the single quote serves to convert the following character into its numeric value. ref. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_20_94_13

Comment: @Matthematics, @dmcontador, @Orwellophile: The issue with special characters lays in `[A-Za-z0-9]`. I have no idea why, but `[A-Za-z]` matches characters with diacritics and `[0-9]` matches number-like characters too (e.g. `½`). Easy fix is to list all the Latin chars and arabic numbers char by char. See modified version of the script [here](https://gitlab.com/tukusejssirs/lnx_scripts/blob/master/bash_functions/rawurlencode.sh). And I have no idea what the minimal Bash version is, but it works on `v5.0.7(1)`. It can process `Jogging «à l'Hèze»`, `é` and `½` or any other chars with diacritics.

Comment: @Matthematics, @dmcontador, @Orwellophile: I was wrong in my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command/10660730#comment103082857_10660730). [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7506695/3408342) using `xxd` is beter and works in any case (for any character). I have updated [my script](https://gitlab.com/tukusejssirs/lnx_scripts/blob/master/bash_functions/rawurlencode.sh). Anyway, it looks like the `rawurldecode()` function works exceptionally well. :)

Comment: @tukusejssirs the link to your script has been updated to: https://gitlab.com/tukusejssirs/lnx_scripts/-/blob/master/bash/functions/rawurlencode.sh

Moreover you are missing the character 'r', sent a PR: https://gitlab.com/tukusejssirs/lnx_scripts/-/merge_requests/1

Thanks!

Comment: With proper UTF-8 encoding support:
`rawurlencode() { local LANG=C ; local IFS= ; while read -n1 -r -d "$(echo -n "\000")" c ; do case "$c" in [-_.~a-zA-Z0-9]) echo -n "$c" ;; *) printf '%%%02x' "'$c" ;;
esac ; done }`. Then: `echo -n "Jogging «à l'Hèze»." | rawurlencode` produces `Jogging%20%c2%ab%c3%a0%20l%27H%c3%a8ze%c2%bb.` as expected.

Comment: @vladr I tested your code, https://github.com/sfinktah/bash/blob/master/rawurlencode.inc.sh and it returned the same result as mine (albiet at 1/100th of the speed).  I agree that it should produce the string you say is expected, since that is also what php's `urlencode` produces, but I don't understand why the function in your comment would work differently for you than for me.  What version of BASH?

Comment: @Orwellophile it's not about the bash version, it's specifically about handling UTF-8 (which your answer explicitly says it does not handle); the key part is `LANG=C` which means that the method will treat the input (hopefully well-formed UTF-8) as bytes for purposes of tokenization and escaping.

Comment: @vladr I just tried your code on Ubuntu 20.4 and it produced `Jogging%20%ab%e0%20l%27H%e8ze%bb.` as does my code, FYI the LANG default on my Ubuntu server is en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 106):

Use Perl's `URI::Escape` module and `uri_escape` function in the second line of your bash script:

```
...

value="$(perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_escape($ARGV[0]);' "$2")"
...
```

**Edit:** Fix quoting problems, as suggested by Chris Johnsen in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: URI::Escape might not be installed, check my answer in that case.

Comment: I fixed this (use `echo`, pipe and `<>`), and now it works even when $2 contains an apostrophe or double-quotes. Thanks!

Comment: You do away with `echo`, too: `value="$(perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_escape($ARGV[0]);' "$2")"`

Comment: Chris Johnsen's version is better. I had ${True} in my test expression and using this via echo tripped up uri_escape / Perl variable expansion.

Comment: @thecoshman are you suggesting that you want to see an answer written in vanilla bash without any outside utilities, e.g. bash4, perl, awk, cat, cut, xxd, etc.? (see other answers below).  (Virtually) anything you write will have some external/version dependency since vanilla bash is not that powerful.  Might was well learn to live with that.  Or perhaps, with herculean effort you could achieve it.  Would you really want to do that rather than write something much, much simpler in perl/python/awk/etc.?

Comment: @jrw32982 maybe I badly expressed my self. Things like sed, awk, cat are tools you can 99.999% guarantee are installed, perl however may not always be on your machine. Yes perl is a fine solution here, but isn't much help in the (not that unlikely) situation you don't/can't have perl (up tight admins for instance).

Comment: @thecoshman My point was that even scripts that use only the set of tools that you claim are in the 99.999% range will be subject to version differences from machine to machine.  Witness the bash4 vs bash3 comments for Orwellophile's answer.  So, I disagree that this is a poor answer due to using perl.  It's just an answer with pre-reqs, just like virtually every answer will be.  FWIW, having perl installed is in the 99%+ range in my experience on Linux, Solaris, AIX, HP/UX.  YMMV.

Comment: @jrw32982 yeah, looking back at it, having another language with which to accomplish this task is good. If I could, I'd take back my downvote, but alas it is currently locked in.

Answer (score 81):

One of variants, may be ugly, but simple:

```bash
urlencode() {
    local data
    if [[ $# != 1 ]]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 string-to-urlencode"
        return 1
    fi
    data="$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} --get --data-urlencode "$1" "")"
    if [[ $? != 3 ]]; then
        echo "Unexpected error" 1>&2
        return 2
    fi
    echo "${data##/?}"
    return 0
}
```

Here is the one-liner version for example (as suggested by [*Bruno*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command#comment21366455_10797966)):

```bash
# Oneliner updated for curl 7.88.1
date | { curl -Gs -w %{url_effective} --data-urlencode @- ./ ||: } | sed "s/%0[aA]$//;s/^[^?]*?\(.*\)/\1/"

# Verification that it works on input without the trailing \n
printf "%s" "$(date)" | { curl -Gs -w %{url_effective} --data-urlencode @- ./ ||: } | sed "s/%0[aA]$//;s/^[^?]*?\(.*\)/\1/"

# Explanation of what the oneliner is doing
date  `# 1. Generate sample input data ` \
  | \
    { `# groups a set of commands as a unit` \
      curl -Gs -w %{url_effective} --data-urlencode @- ./ `# 2. @- means read stdin` \
      ||: `# since the curl command exits 6, add "OR true"` \
    } \
  | sed \
    -e "s/%0[aA]$//"         `# strip trailing \n if present` \
    -e "s/^[^?]*?\(.*\)/\1/" `# strip leading chars up to and including 1st ?`
```

Comment: I think this is a very clever way to reuse cURL's URL encoding.

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant! I really wish you had left it a one line so that people can see how simple it really is. To URL encode the result of the `date` command… `date | curl -Gso /dev/null -w %{url_effective} --data-urlencode @- "" | cut -c 3-` (You have to `cut` the first 2 chars off, because curl's output is a technically a relative URL with a query string.)

Comment: I love how clever this is, but it doesn't seem to work with my curl 7.33.0. Works in a debian wheezy box that has curl 7.26.0.

Comment: @dequis, hmm -- if there's a bug, it's one that was fixed since then (works fine with a macports build of curl 7.48.0 on OS X). Can you isolate how behavior has changed?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy dunno what the bug was, sorry. Just tested with both 7.38.0 and 7.47.1 and it works.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky Your one-liner variant is good but seemingly adds a "%0A" to the end of the encoding. Users beware. The function version does not seem to have this issue.

Comment: To avoid `%0A` at the end, use `printf` instead of `echo`.

Comment: the one liner is fantastic

Comment: This approach is great but it relies on a `curl` command that returns a non-zero code. This can be a problem if `errexit` and `pipefail` options are active.
I solved this particular issue by adding `|| true` to allow the one liner to fail:
`printf "%s" "${1:-}" | curl -Gso /dev/null -w "%{url_effective}" --data-urlencode @- "" | cut -c 3- || true`

Comment: Does not encode equal signs.

Comment: The `-o /dev/null` does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: Some caution is required because `curl` (at least version 7.79.1 om macOS) chooses to encode spaces as `+`. Most URL-encoders use `%20` and decoders expect that; they may not translate the `+` back to a space. It has to do with a weird twist in the [standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#application-x-www-form-urlencoded-percent-encode-set), which uses "an optional boolean spaceAsPlus (default false)" to decide this - apparently `curl` chooses to set it to true. To avoid problems, pipe the result through `sed 's/\+/%20/g'` or something like it.

Comment: In `curl 7.88.1` this one-liner does not seem to work anymore leading to empty value.

Comment: Recent curl versions complain about the URL not being valid: `curl: (3) Could not parse the URL, failed to set query` (only visible without `-s`/`--silent`, strangely `--show-error` does not seem to work for this error).

Answer (score 76):

for the sake of completeness, many solutions using `sed` or `awk` only translate a special set of characters and are hence quite large by code size and also dont translate other special characters that should be encoded.

a safe way to urlencode would be to just encode every single byte - even those that would've been allowed.

```
echo -ne 'some random\nbytes' | xxd -plain | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\(..\)/%\1/g'
```

xxd is taking care here that the input is handled as bytes and not characters.

edit:

xxd comes with the vim-common package in Debian and I was just on a system where it was not installed and I didnt want to install it. The altornative is to use `hexdump` from the bsdmainutils package in Debian. According to the following graph, bsdmainutils and vim-common should have an about equal likelihood to be installed:

http://qa.debian.org/popcon-png.php?packages=vim-common%2Cbsdmainutils&show_installed=1&want_legend=1&want_ticks=1

but nevertheless here a version which uses `hexdump` instead of `xxd` and allows to avoid the `tr` call:

```
echo -ne 'some random\nbytes' | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x"' | sed 's/\(..\)/%\1/g'
```

Comment: `xxd -plain` should happen AFTER `tr -d '\n'` !

Comment: @qdii why? that would not only make it impossible to urlencode newlines but it would also wrongly insert newlines created by xxd into the output.

Comment: @josch. This is just plain wrong.
First, any `\n` characters will be translated by `xxd -plain` into `0a`. Don’t take my word for it, try it yourself: `echo -n -e '\n' | xxd -plain` This proves that your `tr -d '\n'` is useless here as there cannot be any `\n` after `xxd -plain`

Second, `echo foobar` adds its own `\n` character in the end of the character string, so `xxd -plain` is not fed with `foobar` as expected but with `foobar\n`. then `xxd -plain`  translates it into some character string that ends in `0a`, making it unsuitable for the user. You could add `-n` to `echo` to solve it.

Comment: @qdii indeed -n was missing for echo but the `xxd` call belongs in front of the `tr -d` call.

It belongs there so that any newline in `foobar` is translated by `xxd`. The `tr -d` after the `xxd` call is to remove the newlines that xxd produces.

It seems you never have foobar long enough so that `xxd` produces newlines but for long inputs it will. So the `tr -d` is necessary.

In contrast to your assumption the `tr -d` was NOT to remove newlines from the input but from the `xxd` output. I want to keep the newlines in the input.

Your only valid point is, that echo adds an unnecessary newline.

Comment: @qdii and no offence taken - I just think that you are wrong, except for the `echo -n` which I was indeed missing

Answer (score 66):

I find it more readable in python:

```
encoded_value=$(python3 -c "import urllib.parse; print urllib.parse.quote('''$value''')")
```

the triple ' ensures that single quotes in value won't hurt. urllib is in the standard library. It work for example for this crazy (real world) url:

```
"http://www.rai.it/dl/audio/" "1264165523944Ho servito il re d'Inghilterra - Puntata 7
```

Comment: I had some trouble with quotes and special chars with the triplequoting, this seemed to work for basically everything:

encoded_value="$( echo -n "${data}" | python -c "import urllib; import sys; sys.stdout.write(urllib.quote(sys.stdin.read()))" )";

Comment: Python 3 version would be `encoded_value=$(python3 -c "import urllib.parse; print (urllib.parse.quote('''$value'''))")`.

Comment: The `urllib.parse.quote` does not encode forward slashes '/'.

    `urlencode() { python3 -c 'import urllib.parse; import sys; print(urllib.parse.quote(sys.argv[1], safe=""))' "$1" }`

Comment: `python -c 'import urllib, sys; sys.stdout.writelines(urllib.quote_plus(l, safe="/\n") for l in sys.stdin)'` has almost no quoting problems, and *should* be memory/speed efficient (haven't checked, save for squinting)

Comment: It would be much safer to refer to `sys.argv` rather than substituting `$value` into a string later parsed as code. What if `value` contained `''' + __import__("os").system("rm -rf ~") + '''`?

Comment: `python -c "import urllib;print urllib.quote(raw_input())" <<< "$data"`

Comment: It's saying edit queue is full but it would be appropriate to use python3, sys.argv as others have noted, and remove the example because it doesn't work.

Comment: Needed the safe parameter as noted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/how-can-i-percent-encode-url-parameters-in-python/1695199#1695199

Answer (score 37):

I've found the following snippet useful to stick it into a chain of program calls, where URI::Escape might not be installed:

```
perl -p -e 's/([^A-Za-z0-9])/sprintf("%%%02X", ord($1))/seg'
```

([source](http://support.internetconnection.net/CODE_LIBRARY/Perl_URL_Encode_and_Decode.shtml))

Comment: worked for me. I changed it to perl -lpe ... (the letter ell). This removed the trailing newline, which I needed for my purposes.

Comment: FYI, to do the inverse of this, use `perl -pe 's/\%(\w\w)/chr hex $1/ge'` (source: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159253/decoding-url-encoding-percent-encoding)

Comment: Depending on specifically which characters you need to encode, you can simplify this to `perl -pe 's/(\W)/sprintf("%%%02X", ord($1))/ge'` which allows letters, numbers, and underscores, but encodes everything else.

Comment: Thanks for response above! Since the use case is for curl:

That is: `:` and `/` does not need encoding, my final function in my bashrc/zshrc is:
`perl -lpe 's/([^A-Za-z0-9.\/:])/sprintf("%%%02X", ord($1))/seg`

Comment: where do you put the string to be encoded?

Comment: @TobiasFeil it comes from stdin.

Answer (score 28):

If you wish to run `GET` request and use pure curl just add `--get` to  @Jacob's solution.

Here is an example:

```
curl -v --get --data-urlencode "access_token=$(cat .fb_access_token)" https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```

Answer (score 17):

This may be the best one:

```
after=$(echo -e "$before" | od -An -tx1 | tr ' ' % | xargs printf "%s")
```

Comment: This works for me with two additions: 1. replace the -e with -n to avoid adding a newline to the end of the argument and 2. add '%%' to the printf string to put a % in front of each pair of hex digits.

Comment: works after add $ ahead bracket

`after=$(echo -e ...`

Comment: Please explain how this works. The `od` command is not common.

Comment: This does not work with OS X's `od` because it uses a different output format than GNU `od`. For example `printf aa|od -An -tx1 -v|tr \  -` prints `-----------61--61--------------------------------------------------------` with OS X's `od` and `-61-61` with GNU `od`. You could use `od -An -tx1 -v|sed 's/  */ /g;s/ *$//'|tr \  %|tr -d \\n` with either OS X's `od` or GNU `od`. `xxd -p|sed 's/../%&/g'|tr -d \\n` does the same thing, even though `xxd` is not in POSIX but `od` is.

Comment: Although this might work, it escapes every single character

Comment: `echo` should be considered unsafe. It fails if the string you want to output may be interpreted as a parameter (supported parameters are platform-dependent). In this example, there is no output if `$before` is `-n`, which is clearly wrong. Use `printf '%s' "$before"` instead.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a Bash solution which doesn't invoke any external programs:

```
uriencode() {
  s="${1//'%'/%25}"
  s="${s//' '/%20}"
  s="${s//'"'/%22}"
  s="${s//'#'/%23}"
  s="${s//'$'/%24}"
  s="${s//'&'/%26}"
  s="${s//'+'/%2B}"
  s="${s//','/%2C}"
  s="${s//'/'/%2F}"
  s="${s//':'/%3A}"
  s="${s//';'/%3B}"
  s="${s//'='/%3D}"
  s="${s//'?'/%3F}"
  s="${s//'@'/%40}"
  s="${s//'['/%5B}"
  s="${s//']'/%5D}"
  printf %s "$s"
}
```

Comment: This behaves differently between the bash versions. On RHEL 6.9 the bash is 4.1.2 and it includes the single quotes. While Debian 9 and bash 4.4.12 is fine with the single quotes. For me removing the single quotes made it work on both.   s="${s//','/%2C}"

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect your finding, @muni764.

Comment: Just a warning... this won't encode things like the character `á`

Answer (score 15):

Direct link to awk version : http://www.shelldorado.com/scripts/cmds/urlencode
I used it for years and it works like a charm

```
:
##########################################################################
# Title      :  urlencode - encode URL data
# Author     :  Heiner Steven (heiner.steven@odn.de)
# Date       :  2000-03-15
# Requires   :  awk
# Categories :  File Conversion, WWW, CGI
# SCCS-Id.   :  @(#) urlencode  1.4 06/10/29
##########################################################################
# Description
#   Encode data according to
#       RFC 1738: "Uniform Resource Locators (URL)" and
#       RFC 1866: "Hypertext Markup Language - 2.0" (HTML)
#
#   This encoding is used i.e. for the MIME type
#   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
#
# Notes
#    o  The default behaviour is not to encode the line endings. This
#   may not be what was intended, because the result will be
#   multiple lines of output (which cannot be used in an URL or a
#   HTTP "POST" request). If the desired output should be one
#   line, use the "-l" option.
#
#    o  The "-l" option assumes, that the end-of-line is denoted by
#   the character LF (ASCII 10). This is not true for Windows or
#   Mac systems, where the end of a line is denoted by the two
#   characters CR LF (ASCII 13 10).
#   We use this for symmetry; data processed in the following way:
#       cat | urlencode -l | urldecode -l
#   should (and will) result in the original data
#
#    o  Large lines (or binary files) will break many AWK
#       implementations. If you get the message
#       awk: record `...' too long
#        record number xxx
#   consider using GNU AWK (gawk).
#
#    o  urlencode will always terminate it's output with an EOL
#       character
#
# Thanks to Stefan Brozinski for pointing out a bug related to non-standard
# locales.
#
# See also
#   urldecode
##########################################################################

PN=`basename "$0"`          # Program name
VER='1.4'

: ${AWK=awk}

Usage () {
    echo >&2 "$PN - encode URL data, $VER
usage: $PN [-l] [file ...]
    -l:  encode line endings (result will be one line of output)

The default is to encode each input line on its own."
    exit 1
}

Msg () {
    for MsgLine
    do echo "$PN: $MsgLine" >&2
    done
}

Fatal () { Msg "$@"; exit 1; }

set -- `getopt hl "$@" 2>/dev/null` || Usage
[ $# -lt 1 ] && Usage           # "getopt" detected an error

EncodeEOL=no
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case "$1" in
        -l) EncodeEOL=yes;;
    --) shift; break;;
    -h) Usage;;
    -*) Usage;;
    *)  break;;         # First file name
    esac
    shift
done

LANG=C  export LANG
$AWK '
    BEGIN {
    # We assume an awk implementation that is just plain dumb.
    # We will convert an character to its ASCII value with the
    # table ord[], and produce two-digit hexadecimal output
    # without the printf("%02X") feature.

    EOL = "%0A"     # "end of line" string (encoded)
    split ("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F", hextab, " ")
    hextab [0] = 0
    for ( i=1; i<=255; ++i ) ord [ sprintf ("%c", i) "" ] = i + 0
    if ("'"$EncodeEOL"'" == "yes") EncodeEOL = 1; else EncodeEOL = 0
    }
    {
    encoded = ""
    for ( i=1; i<=length ($0); ++i ) {
        c = substr ($0, i, 1)
        if ( c ~ /[a-zA-Z0-9.-]/ ) {
        encoded = encoded c     # safe character
        } else if ( c == " " ) {
        encoded = encoded "+"   # special handling
        } else {
        # unsafe character, encode it as a two-digit hex-number
        lo = ord [c] % 16
        hi = int (ord [c] / 16);
        encoded = encoded "%" hextab [hi] hextab [lo]
        }
    }
    if ( EncodeEOL ) {
        printf ("%s", encoded EOL)
    } else {
        print encoded
    }
    }
    END {
        #if ( EncodeEOL ) print ""
    }
' "$@"
```

Comment: Is there a simple variation to get UTF-8 encoding instead of ASCII?

Answer (score 10):

```
url=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/%/%25/g' -e 's/ /%20/g' -e 's/!/%21/g' -e 's/"/%22/g' -e 's/#/%23/g' -e 's/\$/%24/g' -e 's/\&/%26/g' -e 's/'\''/%27/g' -e 's/(/%28/g' -e 's/)/%29/g' -e 's/\*/%2a/g' -e 's/+/%2b/g' -e 's/,/%2c/g' -e 's/-/%2d/g' -e 's/\./%2e/g' -e 's/\//%2f/g' -e 's/:/%3a/g' -e 's/;/%3b/g' -e 's//%3e/g' -e 's/?/%3f/g' -e 's/@/%40/g' -e 's/\[/%5b/g' -e 's/\\/%5c/g' -e 's/\]/%5d/g' -e 's/\^/%5e/g' -e 's/_/%5f/g' -e 's/`/%60/g' -e 's/{/%7b/g' -e 's/|/%7c/g' -e 's/}/%7d/g' -e 's/~/%7e/g')
```

this will encode the string inside of $1 and output it in $url. although you don't have to put it in a var if you want. BTW didn't include the sed for tab thought it would turn it into spaces

Comment: I get the feeling this is *not* the recommended way to do this.

Comment: explain your feeling please.... because I what I have stated works and I have used it in several scripts so I know it works for all the chars I listed. so please explain why someone would  not use my code and use perl since the title of this is "URLEncode from a bash script" not a perl script.

Comment: sometimes no pearl solution is needed so this can come in handy

Comment: This is not the recommended way to do this because blacklist is bad practice, and this is unicode unfriendly anyway.

Comment: This was the most friendly solution compatible with cat file.txt

Answer (score 9):

Using php from a shell script:

```
value="http://www.google.com"
encoded=$(php -r "echo rawurlencode('$value');")
# encoded = "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com"
echo $(php -r "echo rawurldecode('$encoded');")
# returns: "http://www.google.com"
```

1. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php
2. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php

Answer (score 8):

[uni2ascii](http://www.billposer.org/Software/uni2ascii.html) is very handy:

```
$ echo -ne '你好世界' | uni2ascii -aJ
%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C
```

Comment: This doesn't work for characters *inside* the ASCII range, that need quoting, like `%` and space (that last can be remedied with the `-s` flag)

Answer (score 8):

You can emulate javascript's [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in perl.  Here's the command:

```
perl -pe 's/([^a-zA-Z0-9_.!~*()'\''-])/sprintf("%%%02X", ord($1))/ge'
```

You could set this as a bash alias in `.bash_profile`:

```
alias encodeURIComponent='perl -pe '\''s/([^a-zA-Z0-9_.!~*()'\''\'\'''\''-])/sprintf("%%%02X",ord($1))/ge'\'
```

Now you can pipe into `encodeURIComponent`:

```
$ echo -n 'hèllo wôrld!' | encodeURIComponent
h%C3%A8llo%20w%C3%B4rld!
```

Answer (score 8):

What would parse URLs better than javascript?

```
node -p "encodeURIComponent('$url')"
```

Comment: Out of op question scope. Not bash, not curl. Even if I'm sure works very good if node is available.

Comment: Why down-voting this and not the python/perl answers? Furthermore how this does not respond the original question "How to urlencode data for curl command?". This can be used from a bash script and the result can be given to a curl command.

Comment: I down-voted the others too. The question was how to do this in a bash script. If another language is used like node/js, python or perl, there is no need to use curl directly then.

Comment: There is no need to use curl if you have another language at your disposal but it does not mean you cannot use it. From the bash perspective curl is an external command just as node is. The solution I propose is to use node and curl inside a bash script. Yes you need a dependency but it is still bash. I am not proposing to do the whole work with node. Therefore this is a valid solution to the question "How to urlencode data *for curl* command?". The answer to the question is "urlencode the data with a node one-liner".

Comment: While I didn't bother to downvote, the problem with this command is that it requires data to be properly escaped for use in javascript. Like try it with single quotes and some backslash madness. If you want to use node, you better read stuff from stdin like `node -p 'encodeURIComponent(require("fs").readFileSync(0))'`

Comment: This is my favorite solution because my automation is a mix of bash and `Node.js`, so a dependency on `Node.js` is not a problem, and the solution is simply and readable.

Comment: Be careful with @MichaelKrelin-hacker's solution if you are piping data in from STDIN make sure not to include a trailing newline. For example, `echo | ...` is wrong, while `echo -n | ...` suppresses the newline.

Comment: @MarkStosberg, good point. If newline is undesirable, it may also be trimmed in javascript.

Answer (score 8):

Python 3 based on @sandro's good answer from 2010:

```
echo "Test & /me" | python -c "import urllib.parse;print (urllib.parse.quote(input()))"
```

Test%20%26%20/me

Answer (score 8):

This nodejs-based answer will use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on stdin:

```
uriencode_stdin() {
    node -p 'encodeURIComponent(require("fs").readFileSync(0))'
}

echo -n $'hello\nwörld' | uriencode_stdin
hello%0Aw%C3%B6rld
```

Comment: Best version out there ;)

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to depend on Perl you can also use sed. It's a bit messy, as each character has to be escaped individually. Make a file with the following contents and call it `urlencode.sed`

```
s/%/%25/g
s/ /%20/g
s/ /%09/g
s/!/%21/g
s/"/%22/g
s/#/%23/g
s/\$/%24/g
s/\&/%26/g
s/'\''/%27/g
s/(/%28/g
s/)/%29/g
s/\*/%2a/g
s/+/%2b/g
s/,/%2c/g
s/-/%2d/g
s/\./%2e/g
s/\//%2f/g
s/:/%3a/g
s/;/%3b/g
s//%3e/g
s/?/%3f/g
s/@/%40/g
s/\[/%5b/g
s/\\/%5c/g
s/\]/%5d/g
s/\^/%5e/g
s/_/%5f/g
s/`/%60/g
s/{/%7b/g
s/|/%7c/g
s/}/%7d/g
s/~/%7e/g
s/      /%09/g
```

To use it do the following.

```
STR1=$(echo "https://www.example.com/change&$ ^this to?%checkthe@-functionality" | cut -d\? -f1)
STR2=$(echo "https://www.example.com/change&$ ^this to?%checkthe@-functionality" | cut -d\? -f2)
OUT2=$(echo "$STR2" | sed -f urlencode.sed)
echo "$STR1?$OUT2"
```

This will split the string into a part that needs encoding, and the part that is fine, encode the part that needs it, then stitches back together.

You can put that into a sh script for convenience, maybe have it take a parameter to encode, put it on your path and then you can just call:

```
urlencode https://www.exxample.com?isThisFun=HellNo
```

<sub>[source](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/59936-url-encoding.html)</sub>

Answer (score 7):

For those of you looking for a solution that doesn't need perl, here is one that only needs hexdump and awk:

```
url_encode() {
 [ $# -lt 1 ] && { return; }

 encodedurl="$1";

 # make sure hexdump exists, if not, just give back the url
 [ ! -x "/usr/bin/hexdump" ] && { return; }

 encodedurl=`
   echo $encodedurl | hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x\t"' -e '1/1 "%_c\n"' |
   LANG=C awk '
     $1 == "20"                    { printf("%s",   "+"); next } # space becomes plus
     $1 ~  /0[adAD]/               {                      next } # strip newlines
     $2 ~  /^[a-zA-Z0-9.*()\/-]$/  { printf("%s",   $2);  next } # pass through what we can
                                   { printf("%%%s", $1)        } # take hex value of everything else
   '`
}
```

Stitched together from a couple of places across the net and some local trial and error. It works great!

Answer (score 7):

The question is about doing this in bash and there's no need for python or perl as there is in fact a single command that does exactly what you want - "urlencode".

```bash
value=$(urlencode "${2}")
```

This is also much better, as the above perl answer, for example, doesn't encode all characters correctly. Try it with the long dash you get from Word and you get the wrong encoding.

Note, you need "gridsite-clients" installed to provide this command:

```bash
sudo apt install gridsite-clients
```

Comment: My version of bash (GNU 3.2) doesn't have `urlencode`. What version are you using?

Comment: I have 4.3.42, but the urlencode command is provided by "gridsite-clients". Try installing that and you should be fine.

Comment: So your answer is not better than any that require others things installed (python, perl, lua, …)

Comment: Except that it only requires installing a single utility instead of an entire language (and libraries), plus is super simple and clear to see what it's doing.

Comment: A link first for the package / project page providing this command would have been useful.

Answer (score 7):

Simple PHP option:

```
echo 'part-that-needs-encoding' | php -R 'echo urlencode($argn);'
```

Comment: If the data to be encoded contains any linefeeds, those will be silently dropped by this implementation.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a POSIX function to do that:

```
url_encode() {
   awk 'BEGIN {
      for (n = 0; n < 125; n++) {
         m[sprintf("%c", n)] = n
      }
      n = 1
      while (1) {
         s = substr(ARGV[1], n, 1)
         if (s == "") {
            break
         }
         t = s ~ /[[:alnum:]_.!~*\47()-]/ ? t s : t sprintf("%%%02X", m[s])
         n++
      }
      print t
   }' "$1"
}
```

Example:

```
value=$(url_encode "$2")
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's the node version:

```
uriencode() {
  node -p "encodeURIComponent('${1//\'/\\\'}')"
}
```

Comment: Won't this break if there are any other characters in the string that aren't valid between single quotes, like a single backslash, or newlines?

Comment: Good point. If we're to go to the trouble of escaping all the problematic characters in Bash we might as well perform the replacements directly and avoid `node` altogether. I posted a Bash-only solution. :)

Comment: This variant found elsewhere on the page avoids the quoting issue by reading the value from STDIN: `node -p 'encodeURIComponent(require("fs").readFileSync(0))'`

Answer (score 5):

Here is my version for busybox ash shell for an embedded system, I originally adopted Orwellophile's variant:

```
urlencode()
{
    local S="${1}"
    local encoded=""
    local ch
    local o
    for i in $(seq 0 $((${#S} - 1)) )
    do
        ch=${S:$i:1}
        case "${ch}" in
            [-_.~a-zA-Z0-9]) 
                o="${ch}"
                ;;
            *) 
                o=$(printf '%%%02x' "'$ch")                
                ;;
        esac
        encoded="${encoded}${o}"
    done
    echo ${encoded}
}

urldecode() 
{
    # urldecode <string>
    local url_encoded="${1//+/ }"
    printf '%b' "${url_encoded//%/\\x}"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another php approach:

```
echo "encode me" | php -r "echo urlencode(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));"
```

Comment: `echo` will append a newline character (hex `0xa`). To stop it doing that, use `echo -n`.

Comment: If you have to accept unknown data, always use `printf "%s" "$data"` to avoid interpreting data as commands. If you do e.g. `echo -n $data` and `$data` is a string that starts with `-e` it can do interesting things to the data.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby, for completeness

```
value="$(ruby -r cgi -e 'puts CGI.escape(ARGV[0])' "$2")"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-line conversion using Lua, similar to [blueyed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/urlencode-from-a-bash-script/1710689#1710689) except with all the [RFC 3986 Unreserved Characters](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#sec-2.3) left unencoded (like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/urlencode-from-a-bash-script/296556#296556)):

```
url=$(echo 'print((arg[1]:gsub("([^%w%-%.%_%~])",function(c)return("%%%02X"):format(c:byte())end)))' | lua - "$1")
```

Additionally, you may need to ensure that newlines in your string are converted from LF to CRLF, in which case you can insert a `gsub("\r?\n", "\r\n")` in the chain before the percent-encoding.

Here's a variant that, in [the non-standard style of application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20), does that newline normalization, as well as encoding spaces as '+' instead of '%20' (which could probably be added to the Perl snippet using a similar technique).

```
url=$(echo 'print((arg[1]:gsub("\r?\n", "\r\n"):gsub("([^%w%-%.%_%~ ]))",function(c)return("%%%02X"):format(c:byte())end):gsub(" ","+"))' | lua - "$1")
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I needed to URL encode the hostname. Don't ask why. Being a minimalist, and a Perl fan, here's what I came up with.

```sh
url_encode()
  {
  echo -n "$1" | perl -pe 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_.~-]/sprintf "%%%02x", ord($&)/ge'
  }
```

Works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Having php installed I use this way:

```
URL_ENCODED_DATA=`php -r "echo urlencode('$DATA');"`
```

Comment: that might not handle `$DATA` when it contains single quote `'` characters?

Answer (score 1):

This is the ksh version of orwellophile's answer containing the rawurlencode and rawurldecode functions (link: [How to urlencode data for curl command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/urlencode-from-a-bash-script/10660730#10660730)). I don't have enough rep to post a comment, hence the new post..

```
#!/bin/ksh93

function rawurlencode
{
    typeset string="${1}"
    typeset strlen=${#string}
    typeset encoded=""

    for (( pos=0 ; pos<strlen ; pos++ )); do
        c=${string:$pos:1}
        case "$c" in
            [-_.~a-zA-Z0-9] ) o="${c}" ;;
            * )               o=$(printf '%%%02x' "'$c")
        esac
        encoded+="${o}"
    done
    print "${encoded}"
}

function rawurldecode
{
    printf $(printf '%b' "${1//%/\\x}")
}

print $(rawurlencode "C++")     # --> C%2b%2b
print $(rawurldecode "C%2b%2b") # --> C++
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler pure bash/ksh version without the substring logic. Stated differently the other pure shell solutions reparsed the string to get each character (using parameter substitution `${#str}` for the lenght and `${str:$i:1}` to discover each character). The below method does just one loop over the string to process each character. It is the difference between O(n^2) and O(n). In this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40833433/1344599 Thunderbeef saw ~150x speed improvement on a large text file. This solution is also a shorter oneliner:

```
while IFS='' read -n 1 c ; do [[ "$c" =~ [A-Za-z0-9.~_-] ]] && printf "$c" || printf '%%%02X' "'$c" ; done
```

wrapped in a function, you can either use stdin or a parameter:

```
function urlen_stdin {
  while IFS='' read -n 1 c ; do [[ "$c" =~ [A-Za-z0-9.~_-] ]] && printf "$c" || printf '%%%02X' "'$c" ; done
}
function urlen_param {
  printf '%s' "$1" | while IFS='' read -n 1 c ; do [[ "$c" =~ [A-Za-z0-9.~_-] ]] && printf "$c" || printf '%%%02X' "'$c" ; done
}
function urlen_here {
  while IFS='' read -n 1 c ; do [[ "$c" =~ [A-Za-z0-9.~_-] ]] && printf "$c" || printf '%%%02X' "'$c" ; done <<< "$1"
}

#usage: 
echo -n 'hello !@#$%^&*()[]:;{}\/|-_=+.,? world' | urlen_stdin
urlen_param 'hello !@#$%^&*()[]:;{}\/|-_=+.,? world'
urlen_here 'hello !@#$%^&*()[]:;{}\/|-_=+.,? world'
# all methods render:
hello%20%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26%2A%28%29%5B%5D%3A%3B%7B%7D%2F%7C-_%3D%2B.%2C%3F%20world
```

### Explanation:

`IFS=''` makes whitespace act like normal characters
`read -n 1` reads 1 character at a time
`[[ =~ ]]` is a regex compare. If the character matches, follow the `&&` path, otherwise follow the `||` path
`printf '%%%02X'` print a `%` and the character as a zero-padded length 2 hex code

Comment: I like the `"'$c"` syntax. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: It tells printf to treat the char as an int. Not really sure where it is documented. The man page is close: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html. Find on page: `For decimal conversion`. But that is as a flag, this is an argument. Here is a dedicated SO answer on the topic: https://superuser.com/questions/597620/how-to-convert-ascii-character-to-integer-in-bash

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If it gets the job done, I love it.

Comment: The syntax `"'c"` is documented for the bash builtin `printf` as follows: **if the leading character is a single or double quote, the value is the ASCII value of the following character.**, but that is correct for ASCII characters only; for non-ASCII characters it appears to take the unicode code-point (an integer). For url encoding however, you would prefer the multi-byte UTF-8 values. These can be obtained with `xxd`, but require some manipulation of xxd's output format.

Answer (score 0):

The following is based on Orwellophile's answer, but solves the multibyte
bug mentioned in the comments by setting LC_ALL=C (a trick from vte.sh).
I've written it in the form of function suitable PROMPT_COMMAND, because
that's how I use it.

```
print_path_url() {
  local LC_ALL=C
  local string="$PWD"
  local strlen=${#string}
  local encoded=""
  local pos c o

  for (( pos=0 ; pos<strlen ; pos++ )); do
     c=${string:$pos:1}
     case "$c" in
        [-_.~a-zA-Z0-9/] ) o="${c}" ;;
        * )               printf -v o '%%%02x' "'$c"
     esac
     encoded+="${o}"
  done
  printf "\033]7;file://%s%s\007" "${HOSTNAME:-}" "${encoded}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For one of my cases I found that the NodeJS `url` lib had the simplest solution. Of course YMMV

```
$ urlencode(){ node -e "console.log(require('url').parse(process.argv.slice(1).join('+')).href)" "$@"; }

$ urlencode "https://example.com?my_database_has=these 'nasty' query strings in it"
https://example.com/?my_database_has=these%20%27nasty%27%20query%20strings%20in%20it
```

Comment: why the downvote? The solution might be inefficient, but definitely correct and not hand-crafted like others...

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent answer from Orwellophile, which does include a pure bash option (function rawurlencode), which I've used on my website (shell based CGI script, large number of URLS in response to search requests). The only draw back was high CPU during peak time.

I've found a modified solution, leverage bash "global replace" feature. With this solution processing time for url encode is 4X faster. The solution identify the characters to be escaped, and uses the "global replace" operator (${var//source/replacement}) to process all substitutions. The speed up is clearly from using bash internal loops, over explicit loop.

Performance: On core i3-8100 3.60Ghz. Test case: 1000 URL from stack overflow, similar to this ticket: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command".

- Existing Solution: 0.807 sec
- Optimized Solution: 0.162 sec (5X speedup)

```
url_encode()
{
    local key="${1}" varname="${2:-_rval}" prefix="${3:-_ENCKEY_}"
    local unsafe=${key//[-_.~a-zA-Z0-9 ]/} 
    local -i key_len=${#unsafe}
    local ch ch1 ch0

    while [ "$unsafe" ] ;do
        ch=${unsafe:0:1}
        ch0="\\$ch"
        printf -v ch1 '%%%02x' "'$ch'" 
        key=${key//$ch0/"$ch1"}
        unsafe=${unsafe//"$ch0"}
    done
    key=${key// /+} 

    REPLY="$key"
    # printf "%s" "$REPLY"
    return 0
}
```

As a minor extra, it uses '+' to encode the space. Slightly more compact URL.

Benchmark:

```
function t {
    local key
    for (( i=1 ; i<=$1 ; i++ )) do url_encode "$2" kkk2 ; done
    echo "K=$REPLY"
}

t 1000 "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command"
```

Comment: This seems to hang in infinite loop if input contains multibyte UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Note

- These functions are NOT made to encode URL's data but URLs.
- Put the URLs in a file in a manner of one per line.

```
#!/bin/dash

replaceUnicodes () { # $1=input/output file
    if ! mv -f "$1" "$1".tmp 2>/dev/null; then return 1; fi
    output="$1" awk '
    function hexValue(chr) {
        if(chr=="0") return 0; if(chr=="1") return 1; if(chr=="2") return 2; if(chr=="3") return 3; if(chr=="4") return 4; if(chr=="5") return 5;
        if(chr=="6") return 6; if(chr=="7") return 7; if(chr=="8") return 8; if(chr=="9") return 9; if(chr=="A") return 10;
        if(chr=="B") return 11; if(chr=="C") return 12; if(chr=="D") return 13; if(chr=="E") return 14; return 15 }
    function hexToDecimal(str,  value,i,inc) {
        str=toupper(str); value=and(hexValue(substr(str,length(str),1)),15); inc=1;
        for(i=length(str)-1;i>0;i--) {
            value+=lshift(hexValue(substr(str,i,1)),4*inc++)
        } return value }
    function toDecimal(str, value,i) {
        for(i=1;i<=length(str);i++) {
            value=(value*10)+substr(str,i,1)
        } return value }
    function to32BE(high,low) {
        # return 0x10000+((high-0xD800)*0x400)+(low-0xDC00) }
        return lshift((high-0xD800),10)+(low-0xDC00)+0x10000 }
    function toUTF8(value) {
        if(value<0x80) { 
            return sprintf("%%%02X",value)
        } else if(value>0xFFFF) {
            return sprintf("%%%02X%%%02X%%%02X%%%02X",or(0xF0,and(rshift(value,18),0x07)),or(0x80,and(rshift(value,12),0x3F)),or(0x80,and(rshift(value,6),0x3F)),or(0x80,and(rshift(value,0),0x3F)))
        } else if(value>0x07FF) {
            return sprintf("%%%02X%%%02X%%%02X",or(0xE0,and(rshift(value,12),0x0F)),or(0x80,and(rshift(value,6),0x3F)),or(0x80,and(rshift(value,0),0x3F)))
        } else { return sprintf("%%%02X%%%02X",or(0xC0,and(rshift(value,6),0x1F)),or(0x80,and(rshift(value,0),0x3F))) }
    }
    function trap(str) { sub(/^\\+/,"\\",str); return str }
    function esc(str) { gsub(/\\/,"\\\\",str); return str }
    BEGIN { output=ENVIRON["output"] }
    {
        finalStr=""; while(match($0,/[\\]+u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/)) {
            p=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); num=hexToDecimal(substr(p,RLENGTH-3,4));
            bfrStr=substr($0,1,RSTART-1); $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH,length($0)-(RSTART+RLENGTH-1));
            if(surrogate) {
                surrogate=0;
                if(RSTART!=1 || num<0xD800 || (num>0xDBFF && num<0xDC00) || num>0xDFFF) {
                    finalStr=sprintf("%s%s%s%s",finalStr,trap(highP),bfrStr,toUTF8(num))
                } else if(num>0xD7FF && num<0xDC00) {
                    surrogate=1; high=num; finalStr=sprintf("%s%s",finalStr,trap(highP))
                } else { finalStr=sprintf("%s%s",finalStr,toUTF8(to32BE(high,num))) }
            } else if(num>0xD7FF && num<0xDC00) {
                surrogate=1; highP=p; high=num; finalStr=sprintf("%s%s",finalStr,bfrStr)
            } else { finalStr=sprintf("%s%s%s",finalStr,bfrStr,toUTF8(num)) }
        } finalStr=sprintf("%s%s",finalStr,$0); $0=finalStr

        while(match($0,/[\\]+U[0-9a-fA-F]{8}/)) {
            str=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); gsub(esc(str),toUTF8(hexToDecimal(substr(str,RLENGTH-7,8))),$0)
        }
        while(match($0,/[\\]*&#[xX][0-9a-fA-F]{1,8};/)) {
            str=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); idx=index(str,"#");
            gsub(esc(str),toUTF8(hexToDecimal(substr(str,idx+2,RLENGTH-idx-2))),$0)
        }
        while(match($0,/[\\]*&#[0-9]{1,10};/)) {
            str=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); idx=index(str,"#");
            gsub(esc(str),toUTF8(toDecimal(substr(str,idx+1,RLENGTH-idx-1))),$0)
        }
        printf("%s\n",$0) > output
    }' "$1".tmp
    rm -f "$1".tmp
}

replaceHtmlEntities () { # $1=input/output file
    if ! mv -f "$1" "$1".tmp 2>/dev/null; then return 1; fi
    sed 's/%3[aA]/:/g; s/%2[fF]/\//g; s/&quot;/%22/g; s/&lt;/%3C/g; s/&gt;/%3E/g; s/&nbsp;/%A0/g; s/&cent;/%A2/g; s/&pound;/%A3/g; s/&yen;/%A5/g; s/&copy;/%A9/g; s/&reg;/%AE/g; s/&amp;/\&/g; s/\\*\//\//g' "$1".tmp > "$1"
    rm -f "$1".tmp
}


# "od -v -A n -t u1 -w99999999"
# "hexdump -v -e \47/1 \42%d \42\47"
# Reminder :: Do not encode (, ), [, and ].
toUTF8Encoded () { # $1=input/output file
    if ! mv -f "$1" "$1".tmp 2>/dev/null; then return 1; fi
    if [ -s "$1".tmp ]; then
        # od -A n -t u1 -w99999999 "$1".tmp | \
        hexdump -v -e '/1 "%d "' "$1".tmp | \
        output="$1" awk 'function hexDigit(chr) { if((chr>47 && chr<58) || (chr>64 && chr<71) || (chr>96 && chr<103)) return 1; return 0 }
        BEGIN { output=ENVIRON["output"] }
        {   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                flushed=0; c=$(i);
                if(c==13) { if($(i+1)==10) i++; printf("%s\n",url) > output; url=""; flushed=1
                } else if(c==10) { printf("%s\n",url) > output; url=""; flushed=1
                } else if(c==37) {
                    if(hexDigit($(i+1)) && hexDigit($(i+2))) {
                        url=sprintf("%s%%%c%c",url,$(i+1),$(i+2)); i+=2
                    } else { url=sprintf("%s%%25",url) }
                } else if(c>32 && c<127 && c!=34 && c!=39 && c!=96 && c!=60 && c!=62) {
                    url=sprintf("%s%c",url,c)
                } else { url=sprintf("%s%%%02X",url,c) }
            } if(!flushed) printf("%s\n",url) > output
        }'
    fi
    rm -f "$1".tmp
}
```

Call `replaceUnicodes()` --> `replaceHtmlEntities()` --> `toUTF8Encoded()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a flexible function that:

- can accept either piped input *or* arguments
- handles multi-byte characters and nulls (nulls only work in piped input, not arguments, which is a limitation of bash)
- is based on simple cli tools like `xxd` that are likely already installed on your system, rather than requiring large packages like node, or other components that are not default; and
- the output only percent-encodes as necessary, so it's shorter and more readable.

```bash
rawurlencode () {
    local b
    { [[ $# -gt 0 ]] && printf '%s' "$*" || cat; } \
        | xxd -p \
        | fold -b -w2 \
        | while read -r b
    do
        case $b in
            3[0-9]|[46][^0]|[57][0-9a]|2[de]|5f|7e)
                # alphanumeric or ~.-_
                printf '\x'$b
                ;;
            *)
                printf '%%'${b@U}
                ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

E.g. the commands

```bash
rawurlencode $'hello\nwörld'
```

and

```bash
printf 'hello\nwörld' | rawurlencode
```

both yield

```
hello%0Aw%C3%B6rld
```

It accepts multiple arguments and will concatenate them with `$IFS` (usually space):

```bash
IFS=$'\t' rawurlencode I can\'t believe it\'s not butter\!
```

yields

```
I%09can%27t%09believe%09it%27s%09not%09butter%21
```

Nulls not working from arguments:

```bash
rawurlencode %$'\0'%
```

yields

```
%25%25
```

but

```bash
printf '%%\0%%' | rawurlencode
```

yields

```
%25%00%25
```