# How can I percent-encode URL parameters in Python?

Tags: python, url, encoding, urllib, urlencode

If I do

```
url = "http://example.com?p=" + urllib.quote(query)
```

1. It doesn't encode `/` to `%2F` (breaks OAuth normalization)
2. It doesn't handle Unicode (it throws an exception)

Is there a better library?

Comment: These are not URL parameters, FYI.  You should clarify.

Comment: What is the language-agnostic canonical Stack Overflow question? (That is, only covering the encoding, not *how* it is achieved.)

Comment: @JamieMarshall what should they be called then if not URL parameters?

Comment: @BenCreasy- attributes.  The specification for URL describes parameters as a separate part of the URL (not involving the query string). [reference here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1808.html)  I can't tell you how much time I've lost trying to authenticate an API because they were asking for parameters and I was sending query attributes.

Answer (score 535, accepted):

From [the Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote):

```
urllib.parse.quote(string, safe='/', encoding=None, errors=None)
```

> Replace special characters in string using the `%xx` escape. Letters, digits, and the characters `'_.-~'` are never quoted. By default, this function is intended for quoting the path section of a URL. The optional safe parameter specifies additional ASCII characters that should not be quoted — **its default value is `'/'`**.

That means passing `''` for *safe* will solve your first issue:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.quote('/test')
'/test'
>>> urllib.parse.quote('/test', safe='')
'%2Ftest'
```

(The function `quote` was moved from [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) to `urllib.parse` in Python 3.)

By the way, have a look at [urlencode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode).

---

About the second issue, there was [a bug report about it](https://bugs.python.org/issue1712522) and it was fixed in Python 3.

For Python 2, you can work around it by encoding as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) like this:

```
>>> query = urllib.quote(u"Müller".encode('utf8'))
>>> print urllib.unquote(query).decode('utf8')
Müller
```

Comment: Thanks you, both worked great. urlencode just calls quoteplus many times in a loop, which isn't the correct normalization for my task (oauth).

Comment: the spec: [rfc 2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) defines these as reserved `reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
                    "$" | ","` Which is what urllib.quote is dealing with.

Comment: `urllib.parse.quote` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting)

Comment: Also, in the case of encoding a search query, you maybe better off using quote_plus:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus

1. It encodes slashes by default
2. It also encodes spaces

Comment: `six.moves.urllib.parse.quote(u"Müller".encode('utf8'))` for Python 2 and 3.

Comment: if you wanna retain the colon from http: , do `urllib.parse.quote('http://example.com/some path/').replace('%3A', ':')`

Comment: @chrizonline Just use `urllib.parse.quote(url, safe=':/')`. Even better, encode `some path`, then join strings. This is Python, not PHP.

Comment: safe="" is missing in Python 3 answer!

Answer (score 210):

In Python 3, [`urllib.quote`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) has been moved to [`urllib.parse.quote`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote), and it does handle [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) by default.

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote
>>> quote('/test')
'/test'
>>> quote('/test', safe='')
'%2Ftest'
>>> quote('/El Niño/')
'/El%20Ni%C3%B1o/'
```

Comment: The name `quote` is rather vague as a global. It might be nicer to use something like urlencode: `from urllib.parse import quote as urlencode`.

Comment: Note that there is a function named `urlencode` in `urllib.parse` already that does something completely different, so you'd be better off picking another name or risk seriously confusing future readers of your code.

Comment: (style suggestion: @Luc i agree that `quote` is "rather vague". rather than rename the variable/object to something else you can leave the name fully qualified as `urllib.parse.quote`. leaving it fully qualified does two things: takes a little extra time typing and saves time reading and maintaining the code. )

Answer (score 63):

I think module `requests` is much better. It's based on `urllib3`.

You can try this:

```
>>> from requests.utils import quote
>>> quote('/test')
'/test'
>>> quote('/test', safe='')
'%2Ftest'
```

<sub>My answer is similar to [Paolo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/how-can-i-percent-encode-url-parameters-in-python/13625238#13625238).</sub>

Comment: `requests.utils.quote` is link to python `quote`. See [request sources](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/compat.py#L36).

Comment: `requests.utils.quote` is a thin compatibility wrapper to `urllib.quote` for python 2 and `urllib.parse.quote` for python 3

Comment: without reading the comments, this is creating confusion...

Answer (score 15):

If you're using [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29), you can use [urlquote](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.http.urlquote):

```
>>> from django.utils.http import urlquote
>>> urlquote(u"Müller")
u'M%C3%BCller'
```

Note that changes to Python mean that this is now a legacy wrapper. From the Django 2.1 source code for *django.utils.http*:

```
A legacy compatibility wrapper to Python's urllib.parse.quote() function.
(was used for unicode handling on Python 2)
```

Comment: it's deprecated from Django 3.0+

Answer (score 5):

It is better to use `urlencode` here. There isn't much difference for a single parameter, but, IMHO, it makes the code clearer. (It looks confusing to see a function `quote_plus`! - especially those coming from other languages.)

```
In [21]: query='lskdfj/sdfkjdf/ksdfj skfj'

In [22]: val=34

In [23]: from urllib.parse import urlencode

In [24]: encoded = urlencode(dict(p=query,val=val))

In [25]: print(f"http://example.com?{encoded}")
http://example.com?p=lskdfj%2Fsdfkjdf%2Fksdfj+skfj&val=34
```

### Documentation

- *[urlencode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode)*
- *[quote_plus](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus)*

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method using [furl](https://pypi.org/project/furl/):

```py
import furl

url = "https://httpbin.org/get?hello,world"
print(url)
url = furl.furl(url).url
print(url)
```

Output:

```
https://httpbin.org/get?hello,world
https://httpbin.org/get?hello%2Cworld
```