# Mechanize: TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, mechanize

Trying to fill in a form in order to get the average prices of goods in a city.

```
basket = br.open('http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/')
read_it = basket.read()

# Select form
for form in br.forms():
    print '%r %r %s' % (form.name, form.attrs.get('id'), form.action)
    for control in form.controls:
        print ' ', control.type, control.name, repr(control.value)

br.form['menu_dispatch_form'] = 'Washington, DC, United States'
br.submit()
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Trip cost calculator/trip costs calculator.py", line 50, in <module>
    br.form['menu_dispatch_form'] = 'Washington, DC, United States'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

There's no form name but I thought I could use the form id instead. I found this [website](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/chapters/screen-scraping/) that was helpful but unlike their example I don't have any `text` to put in the `br.form[]`. Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrongly. You need to select a `form`, only then can you assign values to the form controls.

Do you have a `menu_dispatch_form`? Then use `br.select_form("menu_dispatch_form")` to select the form. To add data to the form, you should assign values to the form controls. [This](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720470/using-python-and-mechanize-to-submit-form-data-and-authenticate) should help you with finding and assigning values to form controls.