# Download online PDF files named with special characters

Tags: python, unicode, special-characters

I am using below codes to download online PDF files. It works fine for most files.

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import urllib2
import shutil
import urlparse
import os

def download(url, fileName=None):
    def getFileName(url,openUrl):
        if 'Content-Disposition' in openUrl.info():
            cd = dict(map(
                lambda x: x.strip().split('=') if '=' in x else (x.strip(),''),
                openUrl.info()['Content-Disposition'].split('')))
            if 'filename' in cd:
                filename = cd['filename'].strip("\"'")
                if filename: return filename
        return os.path.basename(urlparse.urlsplit(openUrl.url)[2])

    r = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url))
    try:
        fileName = fileName or getFileName(url,r)
        with open(fileName, 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r,f)
    finally:
        r.close()
```

however for some files with special characters in the address, for example:

```
download(u'http://www.poemhunter.com/i/ebooks/pdf/aogán_ó_rathaille_2012_5.pdf', 'c:\\the_file.pdf')
```

it give a Unicode error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: BTW the `# -*- coding: utf8 -*-` line just tells the Python interpreter to handle UTF-8 in your source code file, it has no affect on how your program itself actually processes UTF-8 / Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I guess this counts as an answer, since it shows an alternative way to handle the URL encoding problem. But I mostly wrote it in response to Mark K's comment in dazedconfused's answer.]

Maybe Acrobat's just being too strict; try another PDF tool.

I just downloaded that PDF using this code in Python 2.6.4 on Puppy Linux (Lupu 5.25):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib
import urlparse

old_URL = u'http://www.poemhunter.com/i/ebooks/pdf/aogán_ó_rathaille_2012_5.pdf'

url_parts = urlparse.urlparse(old_URL)
url_parts = [urllib.quote(s.encode('utf-8')) for s in url_parts]
new_URL = urlparse.urlunparse(url_parts)
print new_URL

urllib.urlretrieve(new_URL, 'test.pdf')
```

The PDF file looks ok to me, though

My PDF reader, epdfview, complains:

`(epdfview:10632): Pango-WARNING **: Invalid UTF-8 string passed to pango_layout_set_text()`

but it seems to display the file ok.

This is what pdfinfo says:

```
Title:          AogÃ¡n Ã Rathaille - poems - 
Creator:        PoemHunter.Com
Producer:       PoemHunter.Com
CreationDate:   Wed May 23 00:44:47 2012
Tagged:         no
Pages:          7
Encrypted:      yes (print:yes copy:no change:no addNotes:no)
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
File size:      50469 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.3
```

I also downloaded it via my browser (Seamonkey 2.31), and as expected it's identical to the file retrieved via Python.

Comment: Nice answer. Should use this way to retrieve the file; just check that if I use `r = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url.encode('utf-8'))` to open this url, `r` will return a file object containing plain html text instead of binary data; though it works fine on some other urls.

Comment: @dazedconfused: Interesting! I haven't noticed that before, but I haven't used `urllib2.Request` myself for a couple of years. You might like to investigate the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package; it makes complicated URL requests much simpler than using than standard modules. Of course, it does have the disadvantage that it's not (yet) a standard module, but it is very popular & easy to install using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Just tried `requests`; it works fine and the PDF file can be opened without any problem after being downloaded; still not sure what causes the problem.

Comment: @PM 2Ring, marvelous! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to encode at this line:

```
r = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url.encode('utf-8'))
```

You need to pass byte strings to `Request`, so you'll have to do `encode()`.

Also, you would probably want to read [Python's Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) and [How to percent-encode url parameters in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/how-to-percent-encode-url-parameters-in-python)

Comment: thanks! it works for the download but the when I tried to open the downloaded file, it gives "Acrobat could not open '[name of file]' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

Comment: Also see [How to percent-encode url parameters in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1695183/4014959)