# URL encode parameters

Tags: python

Was wondering how to url encode my parameters, is this right?

```
 params = {'oauth_version': "1.0", 
              'oauth_nonce': oauth.generate_nonce(), 
              'oauth_timestamp': int(time.time()),
              'oauth_consumer_key': CONSUMER_KEY,
              'oauth_token': access_key,
              'oauth_nonce' : nonce, 
              'oauth_consumer_key': consumer.key,
              'oauth_signature': 'el078a5AXGi43FBDyfg5yWY',
              }
```

***Following this guide:***

> To make the Authorization header, you simply append all the values
>   starting with “OAuth”. Each value must be URL encoded.
>
> ```
> > 1. Authorization: OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website-tm-access.co.nz%2Ftrademe-callback",
> > oauth_consumer_key="C74CD73FDBE37D29BDD21BAB54BC70E422",
> > oauth_version="1.0", oauth_timestamp="1285532322",
> > oauth_nonce="7O3kEe", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
> > oauth_signature="5s3%2Bel078a5AXGi43FBDyfg5yWY%3D"
> ```

Comment: *"is this right?"* - ...does it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to percent-encode url parameters in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/how-to-percent-encode-url-parameters-in-python)

Comment: I see parameters, but I don't see how you're URL-encoding them.

Comment: Maybe not dupplicate, since that's an OAuth issue

Answer (score 0):

You should use urllib.quote_plus or urllib.parse.quote_plus in python 3, which will handle it nicely for you.

The way you want to construct your authorization header from your params is the following:

(python3 version)

```
import urllib
authorization = 'OAuth ' + ', '.join([key + '="' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(value)) + '"' for key, value in params.items()])
http_headers = {'Authorization': authorization}
```

(python2 version)

```
import urllib
authorization = 'OAuth ' + ', '.join([key + '="' + urllib.quote_plus(str(value)) + '"' for key, value in params.items()])
http_headers = {'Authorization': authorization}
```

However, you may want to have a look at existing implementations, such as requests-oauth1. See [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/).

Comment: Hi,
I get TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

Comment: Try to make sure all values in the params dict are cast to strings

Comment: Should I try a for statement and convert i in list to str(i) ?

Comment: I added a cast to string in my code, could you try it?