# Encode the URL according to the the user input

Tags: python

i'm a bit new in python and working  on an API. I'd like to return a URI which accepts my 2 paramaters,which are input (target_group_id, date), this is my base url

```
get_customer_action_by_target_group_url = \
    'https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup?targetGroupID=&date='
```

and this is my function.

```
def get_customer_action_by_target_group(self):
payload = {"TargetGroupID": "%s" % self.TargetGroupID, "Date":"%s" % self.date,
            }
if not self.TargetGroupID or not self.date:
    get_target_group_id = (raw_input("Please provide the target Group id:"))
    get_date = (raw_input("Please provide the date as required:"))
    self.TargetGroupID = get_target_group_id
    self.date = get_date
response = self.send_request(self.get_customer_action_by_target_group_url + self.TargetGroupID +
                              self.date,
                             json.dumps(payload), "GET")
print response, response.text, response.reason
return response
```

This should pass the paramters in my url which needs to look like this: https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup?targetGroupID=19&date=20 july 2017 After passing the date and the target groupe_id , but i'm getting this rather https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup?targetGroupID=%25s&date=%25s7220%20July%202017. How could i fixe this ? any sample of code which could help?? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to percent-encode URL parameters in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/how-to-percent-encode-url-parameters-in-python)

Comment: How the send_request function builds the url? Are you using any framewrok to do that?

Comment: One more suggestion: try to apply the [SRP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). This means: don't mix user interaction with other functionality. In your code, if target_group_id is missing and date is not (or the other way around), the used as asked to input both...

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly urge you to consider using the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) ("HTTP for humans"), which was specifically designed to make solving this kind of problem easier than with the standard library alone.

Given

```
url = 'https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup'
tgid = 19
date = '20 July 2017'
```

you can perform the HTTP request you want with

```
data = {'TargetGroupID': tgid, 'date': date}
requests.get(url, params=data)
```

This will do all the tricky stuff correctly and avoid you having to solve problems that have been solved (even for the gnarly corner cases) many times before.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
>>> get_customer_action_by_target_group_url = 'https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup?targetGroupID={0}&date={1}'
>>> 
>>> targetGroupID=19
>>> date="20 july 2017"
>>> 
>>> get_customer_action_by_target_group_url.format(targetGroupID, date)
'https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup?targetGroupID=19&date=20 july 2017'
```