# Why string python add some number to my string automatically?

Tags: python, rest, get, request

Here is my code.

```
import requests

url ='http://openapi.tago.go.kr/openapi/service/ExpBusArrInfoService/getExpBusTmnList'
data = {
'ServiceKey': u'....ZUH%2BuQNPmHiURbswJkYuWwM4UPzBZj3hQ%2FHafuEGG%2BujFqnf9rvZcodp4McovLUtrgc8rOBAPC3tNLQ%3D%3D',
'tmnNm': '서울'
```

I want to use restAPI, but when I request, the key which I put in tranformed like below.

```
print(http.url)
http://openapi.tago.go.kr/openapi/service/ExpBusArrInfoService/getExpBusTmnList?ServiceKey=Wpb3CsAZUH%252BuQNPmHiURbswJkYuWwM4UPzBZj3hQ%252FHafuEGG%252BujFqnf9rvZcodp4McovLUtrgc8rOBAPC3tNLQ%253D%253D&tmnNm=%EC%84%9C%EC%9A%B8
```

You might notice that it add 25 after '%' . So, request failed. How can I solve this problem? I guess formatting system maybe cause this trouble. But I dont know how fix it. Please help me.

Comment: How you are creating the `http` object?

Comment: Your Url contains elements which need to be escaped, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/how-to-percent-encode-url-parameters-in-python) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to make a request using data already url-encoded. That's why your ServiceKey contains some %xx characters:

```
%2B means '+'
%3D means '='
etc.
```

You need to ensure the string used as service key is raw:

```
ZUH+uQNPmHiURbswJkYuWwM4UPzBZj3hQ/HafuEGG+ujFqnf9rvZcodp4McovLUtrgc8rOBAPC3tNLQ==
```

instead of

```
ZUH%2buQNPmHiURbswJkYuWwM4UPzBZj3hQ%2fHafuEGG%2bujFqnf9rvZcodp4McovLUtrgc8rOBAPC3tNLQ%3d%3d
```

There is a lot of resources on the internet to understand url encoding and decoding. For now, you can make sure your URL is raw by using an [online URL encoder/decoder](https://urldecode.org) or simply [use python API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16566069/1887976).