# Translate russian text to text I can put at link in python

Tags: python, text

I need to translate Russian text to text I can put in a link.
For example, I want to find news about Russian company "Сбербанк". I need to use this link to parse data: https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA&hl=ru&gl=RU&ceid=RU:ru, where %D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0 means "Сбербанк". How can I translate the words like "Сбербанк" into the format, that I can put in the link?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/how-to-percent-encode-url-parameters-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to encode that part, you can use [urllib.parse.quote_plus](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus):

```
import urllib.parse

data = "сбербанк"
print(urllib.parse.quote_plus(data))

# %D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA
```

Or you could simply use the [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) library, which is recommended by the official documentation. It is easier to use and will take care of that for you:

```
import requests

url = "https://news.google.com/rss/search"
payload = {'q': "сбербанк", 
           'hl': 'ru',
           'gl': 'RU',
           'ceid': 'RU:ru'
          }

req = requests.get(url, params=payload)
print(req.url)
# https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA&hl=ru&gl=RU&ceid=RU%3Aru

print(req.text)
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><rss version="2.0" ......
```