# How to encode with python to translate %E4 to ä

Tags: python, encoding

I need to convert a string into a different encoding which I believe is Windows1252, not sure though.

The characters would be:

```
%E4 = ä
%F6 = ö
```

I tried urlencode, quote, quote_plus, encode... nothing did the trick.

Maybe I am using the wrong encoding?

```
'mausebär'.encode('Windows-1252')
```

Should become:

```
'mauseb%e4r'
```

Any ideas how to encode with the same characterset?

Comment: Use `encode('cp1252')` instead.

Comment: You need two steps: First encode string into bytes, then escape the bytes outside of printable ASCII as %..

Comment: @angelogro No, windows-1252 is an alias of cp1252

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for URL quoting with CP-1252 (AKA Windows-1252) encoding. You can use [`urllib.parse.quote`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) with the *encoding* parameter:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.quote('ä', encoding='cp1252')
'%E4'
>>> urllib.parse.quote('ö', encoding='cp1252')
'%F6'
```

Main question about URL quoting: [How to percent-encode URL parameters in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1695183/4518341)