# discord.py How to replace spaces with %20 on API requests

Tags: python, discord.py

Using requests

```
@client.command()
async def command(ctx, search=""):
    response = requests.get('URL'+search)    
    data = response.json()
    await ctx.send(data)
```

But whenever typing the command in discord I have to type %20 whenever there is a space. Is there any way to do that automatically in the code?

Comment: You asked the same question before and it got closed. Instead of making a new account and asking it again, please take a look at the referenced duplicate question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/how-to-percent-encode-url-parameters-in-python), you pretty much got the same answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice in using `urllib.parse.quote` instead of `string.replace()`
To enable the use unicode

For example using this `El Niño` should result into `/El%20Ni%C3%B1o/` which is near impossible to do using `string.replace()`

```
from urllib.parse import quote

@client.command()
async def command(ctx, search=""):
    response = requests.get('URL'+ quote(search, safe=''))    
    data = response.json()
    await ctx.send(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You could use the `string.replace()` method.

```
@client.command()
async def command(ctx, search=""):
    response = requests.get('URL'+search.replace(" ", "%20"))    
    data = response.json()
    await ctx.send(data)
```