# How can I encode string in python as the same as javascript escape?

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm

if I escape '가온' in javascript,

the result would be:

```
escape('가온')
'%uAC00%uC628'
```

I want to get the same result like the js in python.

However, if I encode as ascii like:

```
byte_string= "누리".encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')
b'\\ub204\\ub9ac'
```

the result isn't same. How can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is confusing in your question: first you encode '가온' then '누리'.

I think encoding with `'backslashreplace'` can work as long as you decode and replace the backslashes with `%`:

```
"가온".encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace').decode().replace('\\', '%')
```

Output:

```
%uac00%uc628
```

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript escape() is URL escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape).

You can get this using [urllib in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/how-can-i-percent-encode-url-parameters-in-python).

Note that URLs may have multiple different encodings for the same characters. However any valid URL parses should accept any encoding.