# Complete URL encoding

Tags: url, encoding, urlencode

Anyone know of a tool to completely encode a string to URL encoding? Best known example is something to convert space character to %20. I want to do this for every single character. What's a good tool for this (linux)?

thanks everyone for down voting, if i cared what language i would have specified. couldnt find anything useful in the other post linked below so i wrote this. this is good enough for me, might be good enough for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Treats all args as one big string. Inserts implicit spaces between args.
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc == 1)
    {
        printf("Need something to encode.");
        return 1;
    }
    int count = 0;
    while(++count < argc)
    {
        char *input = argv[count];
        while(*input != '\0')
        {
            printf("%%%x", *input);
            input++;
        }
        printf("%%20");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Linux doesn't tell us your development environment.  What language are you using?

Comment: "If I cared what language I would have specified." If you *don't* care, there is no possible answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this SO question:

- [How to urlencode data for curl command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/urlencode-from-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

Which programming language?  You can even do something client-side...

Answer (score 0):

i modified this of the other link

```
perl -p -e 's/(.)/sprintf("%%%02X", ord($1))/seg'
```

it works nice enough..
run this.. type in what you want to convert..(or pipe it through)  and it'll output everything  %encoded