# Getting the URLs for the first Google search results in a shell script

Tags: bash

It's relatively easy to parse the output of the AJAX API using a scripting language:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
import json

base = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&'
query = urllib.urlencode({'q' : "something"})
response = urllib.urlopen(base + query).read()
data = json.loads(response)
print data['responseData']['results'][0]['url']
```

But are there any better ways to do something similar with just basic shell scripting? If you just curled the API page, how should you encode the URL parameters or parse JSON?

Comment: Is there a problem with your current escaping?  I don't see any problem with using urlencode.

Comment: @Xepo Just that it depends on Python. But based on [URLEncode from a bash script - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/urlencode-from-a-bash-script) it does really seem like one of the most reasonable methods.

Comment: @Lri Is this a bash or a pyton question?, please CONSIDER removing the [bash] tag

Comment: @nhed I'm trying to replace the Python example with a bash script.

Comment: Maybe just use [`googlecl`](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/)?

Comment: @Daenyth It doesn't support search (yet?).

Comment: @Lri: Hmm, so it doesn't. I need moar rtfm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using curl's --data-urlencode option to encode the query parameter and just sed for extracting the first result.

`curl -s --get --data-urlencode "q=example" http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0 | sed 's/"unescapedUrl":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/;s/.*GwebSearch",//'`

Comment: This solution seems to only return the last of 4 results for me

Comment: `The Google Web Search API is no longer available. Please migrate to the Google Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)`

Answer (score 5):

many years later, you can install [googler](https://github.com/jarun/googler)

`googler -n 1 -c in -l en search something here --json`

you can control the number of output page using the n flag.

To get only the url, simply pipe it to:

```
grep "\"url\""|tr -s ' ' |cut -d ' ' -f3|tr -d "\""
```

Comment: An easier way to extract just the URL is via [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/): `jq -r '.[].url'`.

Answer (score 4):

@Lri - Here is a script I personally use for my purpose of command line tools & scripts. It uses the command line utility "lynx" for dumping the URLs. Script can be downloaded from [HERE](http://wtfuzz.com/code/gocmd.sh) and code view is [HERE](http://wtfuzz.com/code/gocmd.sh.txt).
Here is the code for your reference,

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
echo ""
echo ".=========================================================."
echo "|                                                         |"
echo "|  COMMAND LINE GOOGLE SEARCH                             |"
echo "|  ---------------------------------------------------    |"
echo "|                                                         |"
echo "|  Version: 1.0                                           |"
echo "|  Developed by: Rishi Narang                             |"
echo "|  Blog: www.wtfuzz.com                                   |"
echo "|                                                         |"
echo "|  Usage: ./gocmd.sh <search strings>                     |"
echo "|  Example: ./gocmd.sh example and test                   |"
echo "|                                                         |"
echo ".=========================================================."
echo ""

if [ -z $1 ]
then
 echo "ERROR: No search string supplied."
 echo "USAGE: ./gocmd.sh <search srting>"
 echo ""
 echo -n "Anyways for now, supply the search string here: "
 read SEARCH
else
 SEARCH=$@
fi

URL="http://google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q="
STRING=`echo $SEARCH | sed 's/ /%20/g'`
URI="$URL%22$STRING%22"

lynx -dump $URI > gone.tmp
sed 's/http/\^http/g' gone.tmp | tr -s "^" "\n" | grep http| sed 's/\ .*//g' > gtwo.tmp
rm gone.tmp
sed '/google.com/d' gtwo.tmp > urls
rm gtwo.tmp

echo "SUCCESS: Extracted `wc -l urls` and listed them in '`pwd`/urls' file for reference."
echo ""
cat urls
echo ""

#EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Untested approach as I don't have access to a unix box currently ...

Assuming "test" is the query string,  you could use a simple wget on the following url 
http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=705&q=test&btnI=Google+Search&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=test&fp=3cc29334ffc8c2c

This would leverage Google's "I'm feeling lucky" functionality and wget the first url for you. You may be able to clean up the above url a bit too.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me without `biw`, `bih`, and `fp` parameters.

Comment: Yeah, only the btnI parameter appears to be relevant. This works for me as a single-line #!/bin/sh shell script, where I am restricting the search to developer.mozilla.org (probably not your use case, but whatever -- I have this saved as "jsdoc"): `exec firefox "https://www.google.com/search?btnI=Google+Search&q=site%3Adeveloper.mozilla.org+$1"`

Answer (score 1):

Lri's answer only returned the last result for me and i needed the top so I changed it to:

```
JSON=$(curl -s --get --data-urlencode "q=QUERY STRING HERE" http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0 | python -mjson.tool)
response=$(echo "$JSON" | sed -n -e 's/^.*responseStatus\": //p')
if [ $response -eq 200 ] ; then 
    url=$(echo "$JSON" | egrep "unescapedUrl" | sed -e '1!d' -e "s/^.*unescapedUrl\": \"//" -e "s/\".*$//")
    echo "Success! [$url]"
    wget $url;
else 
    echo "FAILED! [$response]" 
fi
```

Its not as compact as I'd like but in a rush.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference: By November 2013, you will need to replace the `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web` calls completely.

Most likely, it has to be replaced with Custom Search Engine (CSE). The problem is that you won't be able to get "global" results from CSE. Here is a nice tip on how to do this: http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msg/customsearch/0aoS-bXgnEM/lwlZ6_IyVDQJ.