# How to decode URL-encoded string in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, urldecode

I have a file with a list of user-agents which are encoded.
E.g.:

```
Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Macintosh%3B%20U%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010.6%3B%20en
```

I want a shell script which can read this file and write to a new file with decoded strings.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en
```

I have been trying to use this example to get it going but it is not working so far.

```
$ echo -e "$(echo "%31+%32%0A%33+%34" | sed 'y/+/ /; s/%/\\x/g')"
```

My script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.log; do
  echo -e "$(cat $f | sed 'y/+/ /; s/%/\x/g')" > y.log
done
```

Comment: line 5: 'x' should be double escaped (`s/%/\x/g` -> `s/%/\\x/g`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Will try with double escape. Dont know how I missed it when I copied it from somewhere else. Will update.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159253/decoding-url-encoding-percent-encoding

Comment: @F. Hauri What about the last answer(sorted by highest score)?

Comment: @VictorLee This kind of function are mostly used to populate variables. Using ***forks***  each time you have to *urldecode* is overkill and counter productive

Answer (score 162):

Here is a simple one-line solution.

```
$ function urldecode() { : "${*//+/ }"; echo -e "${_//%/\\x}"; }
```

It may look like perl :) but it is just pure bash. No awks, no seds ... no overheads. Using the : builtin, special parameters, pattern substitution and the echo builtin's -e option to translate hex codes into characters. See bash's manpage for further details. You can use this function as separate command

```
$ urldecode https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Durldecode%2Bbash
https://google.com/search?q=urldecode+bash
```

or in variable assignments, like so:

```
$ x="http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Durldecode%2Bbash"
$ y=$(urldecode "$x")
$ echo "$y"
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=urldecode+bash
```

Comment: Your example does not work: ` line 3: urldecode: command not found`

Comment: Would love some more explanation on the pattern substitution. This function works for me, but it changes the characters in a way that makes file paths not work with the unzip function.

Comment: @JustinPutney `${*//+/ }` will replace *all* `+` with space and `${_//%/\\x}` will replace *all* `%` with `\x`.

Comment: just want to mention this is horrendously slow for me; for 50k urls, `bash: 0m3.767s python: 0m0.200s` (python one liner below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21693459/1695680)

Comment: can you point to the `:` documentation?  I thought `:` was a no-op in bash

Comment: @nhed – `:` _is_ a no-op in bash, but this code plays on the value of `$_`, which “expands to the last argument to the previous simple command” (which is to say this is a perl-level obfuscation). It’d be more legible as `urldecode() { local i="${*//+/ }"; echo -e "${i//%/\\x}"; }` (replace each `+` with a space, then replace each `%` with `\x` so bash knows to interpret the escape sequences properly).

Comment: @8bitjunkie, you need to insert "function" ahead of the example like this:
`function urldecode() { : "${*//+/ }"; echo -e "${_//%/\\x}"; }`
And then you can execute the function like so:
`urldecode "Current%3A+7995%28Mbps%29+%2F+Limit+5000%28Mbps%29"`
Result:
`Current: 7995(Mbps) / Limit 5000(Mbps)`

Comment: What about the other way around, can I encode an URL likewise?

Comment: This is a work of art. Thank you.

Comment: The variable assignment example, as shown, will not preserve trailing newlines that the parameter value may have. Consider a query string of `x=v%0A%0A%0A` (https://httpbin.org/get?x=v%0A%0A%0A). `x=v%0A%0A%0A; y=$(urldecode "$x")` results in `y` having the value of just `v`. The newlines are missing. The [usual technique](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248229) for working around this flaw of command substitution may be used to handle this situation.

Comment: While this _does_ decode percent-encoding, the use of `echo -e` will cause other backslash escapes in the URL to be translated, too. For example, it will replace `?q=\n+escape` to `?q=`, followed by a newline, followed by a space and `escape`.

Answer (score 60):

If you are a **Python** developer, this may be preferable:

For [Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html#module-urllib) (default):

```
echo -n "%21%20" | python3 -c "import sys; from urllib.parse import unquote; print(unquote(sys.stdin.read()));"
```

For [Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#module-urllib) (deprecated):

```
echo -n "%21%20" | python -c "import sys, urllib as ul; print ul.unquote(sys.stdin.read());"
```

[urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html#module-urllib) is really good at handling URL parsing.

Comment: Nice, but I would change a little bit to use argv and use is as an alias. Here is an example for encoding: alias encode='python2 -c "import sys, urllib as ul; print ul.quote(sys.argv[1]);"'

Comment: Modified for python 3: `echo "%21%20" |  python -c "import sys; from urllib.parse import unquote; print(unquote(sys.stdin.read()));"`

Comment: if you want to convert `+` to blank, for python2, you can use `unquote_plus()`

Comment: Unlike all the other solutions, this is practical in an interactive shell

Comment: `function urldecode() { python -c "import sys; from urllib.parse import unquote; print(unquote(sys.argv[1]));" $1 }`

Comment: Love this solution! A slight modification to take files from stdin will look like this ```python3 -c "import sys; from urllib.parse import unquote_plus; print(unquote_plus(sys.stdin.read()));" < input_file```

Comment: Even if you're not a python developer, learn to love one-liners.

Answer (score 25):

With BASH, to read the per cent encoded URL from standard in and decode:

```
while read; do echo -e ${REPLY//%/\\x}; done
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to signal the end of file(EOF) and quit gracefully.

You can decode the contents of a file by setting the file to be standard in:

```
while read; do echo -e ${REPLY//%/\\x}; done < file
```

You can decode input from a pipe either, for example:

```
echo 'a%21b' | while read; do echo -e ${REPLY//%/\\x}; done
```

- The read built in command reads standard in until it sees a Line Feed character. It sets a variable called `REPLY` equal to the line of text it just read.
- `${REPLY//%/\\x}` replaces all instances of '%' with '\x'.
- `echo -e` interprets `\xNN` as the ASCII character with hexadecimal value of `NN`.
- while repeats this loop until the read command fails, eg. EOF has been reached.

The above does not change '+' to ' '. To change '+' to ' ' also, like guest's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37840948/2980321):

```
while read; do : "${REPLY//%/\\x}"; echo -e ${_//+/ }; done
```

- `:` is a BASH builtin command. Here it just takes in a single argument and does nothing with it.
- The double quotes make everything inside one single parameter.
- `_` is a special parameter that is equal to the last argument of the previous command, after argument expansion. This is the value of `REPLY` with all instances of '%' replaced with '\x'.
- `${_//+/ }` replaces all instances of '+' with ' '.

This uses only BASH and doesn't start any other process, similar to guest's answer.

Comment: The decoding of `+` to SPACE should occur _before_ the percent decoding. See guest's answer for an example of the correct order.

Comment: `: "${REPLY//%/\\x}"; echo -e ${_//+/ }` The order here is replace `%` with `\x`, replace `+` with ' ', interpret characters with `\xNN` notation. Why do you think it matters whether you replace % characters first or + characters @RobinA.Meade ?

Comment: You're right, sorry. I see now your answer _does_ replace `+` with SPACE before the `\xNN` are evaluated. My test string was `The time is 2013-12-31T14:00:00+00:00` which I encoded at https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ .Your answer correctly decodes it with the `+` in the time stamp preserved.

Answer (score 19):

This is what seems to be working for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
urldecode(){
  echo -e "$(sed 's/+/ /g;s/%\(..\)/\\x\1/g;')"
}

for f in /opt/logs/*.log; do
    name=${f##/*/}
    cat $f | urldecode > /opt/logs/processed/$HOSTNAME.$name
done
```

Replacing '+'s with spaces, and % signs with '\x' escapes, and letting echo interpret the \x escapes using the '-e' option was not working. For some reason, the cat command was printing the % sign as its own encoded form %25. So sed was simply replacing %25 with \x25. When the -e option was used, it was simply evaluating \x25 as % and the output was same as the original.

**Trace:**

*Original:* Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Macintosh%3B%20U%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010.6%3B%20en

*sed:* Mozilla\x252F5.0\x2520\x2528Macintosh\x253B\x2520U\x253B\x2520Intel\x2520Mac\x2520OS\x2520X\x252010.6\x253B\x2520en

*echo -e:* Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Macintosh%3B%20U%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010.6%3B%20en

**Fix:** Basically ignore the 2 characters after the % in sed.

*sed:* Mozilla\x2F5.0\x20\x28Macintosh\x3B\x20U\x3B\x20Intel\x20Mac\x20OS\x20X\x2010.6\x3B\x20en

*echo -e:* Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en

Not sure what complications this would result in, after extensive testing, but works for now.

Comment: Works, but there should be a `\1` after `\\x` like `echo -e "$(sed 's/+/ /g;s/%\(..\)/\\x\1/g;')"`

Comment: As @svante wrote, the `\1` is missing.  I've edited the answer to include it.  (Plus a couple small formatting/grammar changes to meet the 6-character minimum edit requirement.)

Comment: Best answer for me. Simple, takes input from STDIN, no special tools used.

Comment: For a POSIX-compatible version of this, use `printf '%b\n'`instead of `echo -e`.

Answer (score 8):

Bash script for doing it in native Bash ([original source](https://gist.github.com/cdown/1163649)):

```
LANG=C

urlencode() {
    local l=${#1}
    for (( i = 0 ; i < l ; i++ )); do
        local c=${1:i:1}
        case "$c" in
            [a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]) printf "$c" ;;
            ' ') printf + ;;
            *) printf '%%%.2X' "'$c"
        esac
    done
}

urldecode() {
    local data=${1//+/ }
    printf '%b' "${data//%/\x}"
}
```

If you want to urldecode file content, just put the file content as an argument.

Here's a test that will run halt if the decoded encoded file content differs (if it runs for a few seconds, the script probably works correctly):

```
while true
  do cat /dev/urandom | tr -d '\0' | head -c1000 > /tmp/tmp;
     A="$(cat /tmp/tmp; printf x)"
     A=${A%x}
     A=$(urlencode "$A")
     urldecode "$A" > /tmp/tmp2
     cmp /tmp/tmp /tmp/tmp2
     if [ $? != 0 ]
       then break
     fi
done
```

Comment: Note that your urldecode assumes the data contains no backslash.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: I believe backslashes are not allowed in properly %-encoded strings

Answer (score 8):

### bash idiom for url-decoding

Here is a bash idiom for url-decoding a string held in variabe `x` and assigning the result to variable `y`:

```
: "${x//+/ }"; printf -v y '%b' "${_//%/\\x}"
```

Unlike the accepted answer, it **preserves trailing newlines** during assignment. (Try assigning the result of url-decoding `v%0A%0A%0A` to a variable.)

It also is fast. It is **6700% faster** at assigning the result of url-decoding to a variable than the accepted answer.

Caveat: It is not possible for a bash variable to contain a NUL. For example, any bash solution attempting to decode `%00` and assign the result to a variable will not work.

### Benchmark details

function.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
urldecode() { : "${*//+/ }"; echo -e "${_//%/\\x}"; }
x=%21%20
for (( i=0; i<5000; i++ )); do
  y=$(urldecode "$x")
done
```

idiom.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
x=%21%20
for (( i=0; i<5000; i++ )); do
  : "${x//+/ }"; printf -v y '%b' "${_//%/\\x}"
done
```

```
$ hyperfine --warmup 5 ./function.sh ./idiom.sh
Benchmark #1: ./function.sh
  Time (mean ± σ):      2.844 s ±  0.036 s    [User: 1.728 s, System: 1.494 s]
  Range (min … max):    2.801 s …  2.907 s    10 runs
 
Benchmark #2: ./idiom.sh
  Time (mean ± σ):      42.4 ms ±   1.0 ms    [User: 40.7 ms, System: 1.1 ms]
  Range (min … max):    40.5 ms …  44.8 ms    64 runs
 
Summary
  './idiom.sh' ran
   67.06 ± 1.76 times faster than './function.sh'
```

### If you really want a function ...

If you really want a function, say for readability reasons, I suggest the following:

```sh
# urldecode [-v var ] argument
#
#   Urldecode the argument and print the result.
#   It replaces '+' with SPACE and then percent decodes.
#   The output is consistent with https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/
#
# Options:
#   -v var    assign the output to shell variable VAR rather than
#             print it to standard output
#
urldecode() {
  local assign_to_var=
  local OPTIND opt
  while getopts ':v:' opt; do
    case $opt in
      v)
        local var=$OPTARG
        assign_to_var=Y
        ;;
      \?)
        echo "$FUNCNAME: error: -$OPTARG: invalid option" >&2
        return 1
        ;;
      :)
        echo "$FUNCNAME: error: -$OPTARG: this option requires an argument" >&2
        return 1
        ;;
      *)
        echo "$FUNCNAME: error: an unexpected execution path has occurred." >&2
        return 1
        ;;
    esac
  done
  shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"
  # Convert all '+' to ' '
  : "${1//+/ }"
  # We exploit that the $_ variable (last argument to the previous command
  # after expansion) contains the result of the parameter expansion
  if [[ $assign_to_var ]]; then
    printf -v "$var" %b "${_//%/\\x}"
  else
    printf %b "${_//%/\\x}"
  fi
}
```

**Example 1:** Printing the result to stdout

```
x='v%0A%0A%0A'
urldecode "$x" | od -An -tx1
```

*Result:*

```
 76 0a 0a 0a
```

**Example 2:** Assigning the result of decoding to a shell variable:

```
x='v%0A%0A%0A'
urldecode -v y "$x"
echo -n "$y" | od -An -tx1
```

*(same result)*

This function, while not as fast as the idiom above, is still 1300% faster than the accepted answer at doing assignments due to no subshell being involved. In addition, as shown in the example's output, it preserves trailing newlines due to no command substitution being involved.

Comment: Nice! Consider `urldecode() { local -n var=$1;shift;: "${*//+/ }"; printf -v var %b "${_//%/\\x}"; }`!

Comment: @F.Hauri Your function gets the job done of efficiently assigning to a shell variable. Nice! I modeled my function after `printf -v var ...`, to give the flexibility of printing to stdout or assigning to a `var`, but it is true that often such flexibility will not be needed.

Comment: Or this: `urldecode() { local ret=($'\n');: "${1//+/ }";printf ${2+-v} $2 %b%s "${_//%/\\x}" "${ret[$#-1]}";}`. Where you have to quote (or double-quote)  URL, then **optional** 2nd arg is varname if submited. (If not, decoded url will be printed **with** a newline.)

Comment: @F.Hauri That's quite clever! Yes, that is a good alternative to the function I offered. Both give the user the flexibility of assigning to a variable or printing to stdout.

Comment: In your function, `: "${1//+/ }";` could be placed **before** `if [[ $assign_to_var...` so you don't have to repeat them! **And** In your function, use `return 1` instead of `exit`!!

Comment: Thank you @F.Hauri ! I incorporated your suggestion and fixed that `exit` vs `return` bug.

Answer (score 7):

If you have php installed on your server, you can "cat" or even "tail" any file, with url encoded strings very easily.

```
tail -f nginx.access.log | php -R 'echo urldecode($argn)."\n";'
```

Comment: Never looked at `-R` before, TIL about `$argn` (and `$argi`)! Reference (^F `-R`): http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: You can also pass it in as an argument: `php -r 'echo urldecode($argv[1]),"\n";' Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Macintosh%3B%20U%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010.6%3B%20en`

Answer (score 7):

```sh
perl -pi.back -e 'y/+/ /;s/%([\da-f]{2})/pack H2,$1/gie' ./*.log
```

With `-i` updates the files in-place (some `sed` implementations have borrowed that from `perl`) with `.back` as the backup extension.

`s/x/y/e` substitutes `x` with the **e**valuation of the `y` perl code.

The perl code in this case uses `pack` to pack the hex number captured in `$1` (first parentheses pair in the regexp) as the corresponding character.

An alternative to `pack` is to use `chr(hex($1))`:

```sh
perl -pi.back -e 'y/+/ /;s/%([\da-f]{2})/chr hex $1/gie' ./*.log
```

If available, you could also use `uri_unescape()` from `URI::Escape`:

```sh
perl -pi.back -MURI::Escape -e 'y/+/ /;$_=uri_unescape$_' ./*.log
```

Comment: This example would be even better with a few words of explanation.

Answer (score 6):

As [@barti_ddu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520394/barti-ddu) said in the comments, `\x` "should be [double-]escaped".

```
% echo -e "$(echo "Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Macintosh%3B%20U%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010.6%3B%20en" | sed 'y/+/ /; s/%/\\x/g')"
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en
```

Rather than mixing up Bash and sed, I would do this all in Python. Here's a rough cut of how:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import os
import urllib

for logfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.log')):
    with open(logfile) as current:
        new_log_filename = logfile + '.new'
        with open(new_log_filename, 'w') as new_log_file:
            for url in current:
                unquoted = urllib.unquote(url.strip())
                new_log_file.write(unquoted + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for the script. Will give the sed version one more shot and take the python route if that fails. I read somewhere that the sed approach was faster. Is that true. I will have a few GB sized files to process every hour and can use all the advantage.

Comment: @user785717: Hopefully that will work for you. I've no idea which will perform better on your data. `time` is your friend.

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to share this other solution, pure bash:

```
encoded_string="Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Macintosh%3B%20U%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010.6%3B%20en"
printf -v decoded_string "%b" "${encoded_string//\%/\\x}"
echo $decoded_string
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en
```

Comment: You missed one backslash before `\x`!: `printf -v encoded_string "%b" "${encoded_string//\%/\\x}"`! But you was 1st to suggest `printf -v`!!

Comment: Or as a function streaming output (so it can handle `%00`: `url::decode(){ printf %b "${@//\%/\\x}";}`

Comment: Shortened to `printf "%b\n" "${encoded_string//\%/\\x}"`

Answer (score 6):

Building upon some of the other answers, but for the POSIX world, could use the following function:

```
url_decode() {
    printf '%b\n' "$(sed -E -e 's/\+/ /g' -e 's/%([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/\\x\1/g')"
}
```

It uses `printf '%b\n'` because there is no `echo -e` and breaks the `sed` call to make it easier to read, forcing `-E` to be able to use references with `\1`. It also forces what follows `%` to look like some hex code.

Comment: sadly, the %b is not enforced by POSIX:  
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html

"An additional conversion specifier character, b, shall be supported ..."
shall is not must and here (ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS/dash) it does not work.

Answer (score 4):

With sed:

```
#!/bin/bash
URL_DECODE="$(echo "$1" | sed -E 's/%([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/\\x\1/g;s/\+/ /g'"
echo -e "$URL_DECODE"
```

- `s/%([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/\\x\1/g` replaces % with \x to transform urlencoded to hexadecimal
- `s/\+/ /g` replace + to space ' ', in case using + in query string

Just save it to `decodeurl.sh` and make it executable with `chmod +x decodeurl.sh`

If you need a way do encode too, this complete code will help:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Enconding e Decoding de URL com sed
#
# Por Daniel Cambría
# daniel.cambria@bureau-it.com
#
# jul/2021

function url_decode() {
echo "$@" \
    | sed -E 's/%([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/\\x\1/g;s/\+/ /g'
}

function url_encode() {
    # Conforme RFC 3986
    echo "$@" \
    | sed \
    -e 's/ /%20/g' \
    -e 's/:/%3A/g' \
    -e 's/,/%2C/g' \
    -e 's/\?/%3F/g' \
    -e 's/#/%23/g' \
    -e 's/\[/%5B/g' \
    -e 's/\]/%5D/g' \
    -e 's/@/%40/g' \
    -e 's/!/%41/g' \
    -e 's/\$/%24/g' \
    -e 's/&/%26/g' \
    -e "s/'/%27/g" \
    -e 's/(/%28/g' \
    -e 's/)/%29/g' \
    -e 's/\*/%2A/g' \
    -e 's/\+/%2B/g' \
    -e 's/,/%2C/g' \
    -e 's/;/%3B/g' \
    -e 's/=/%3D/g'
}

echo -e "URL decode: " $(url_decode "$1")
echo -e "URL encode: " $(url_encode "$1")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ UENC='H%C3%B6he %C3%BCber%20dem%20Meeresspiegel'
$ UTF8=$(echo -e "${UENC//%/\\x}")
$ echo $UTF8
Höhe über dem Meeresspiegel
$
```

`-e` allows `/`

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk`:

```sh
LC_ALL=C gawk -vRS='%[[:xdigit:]]{2}' '
  RT {RT = sprintf("%c",strtonum("0x" substr(RT, 2)))}
  {gsub(/\+/," ");printf "%s", $0 RT}'
```

Would take URI-encoded on stdin and print the decoded output on stdout.

We set the record separator as a regexp that matches a `%XX` sequence. In GNU `awk`, the input that matched it is stored in the RT special variable. We extract the hex digits from there, append to "0x" for `strnum()` to turn into a number, passed in turn to `sprintf("%c")` which in the C locale would convert to the corresponding byte value.

Answer (score 2):

Updating [Jay's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21693459/4645455) answer for Python 3.5+:
`echo "%31+%32%0A%33+%34" | python -c "import sys; from urllib.parse import unquote ; print(unquote(sys.stdin.read()))"`

Still, [brendan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42636717/4645455) bash solution with explanation seems more direct and elegant.

Answer (score 2):

With the `zsh` shell (instead of `bash`), the only shell whose variables can hold any byte value including NUL (encoded as `%00`):

```
set -o extendedglob +o multibyte
string='Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Macintosh%3B%20U%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010.6%3B%20en'
decoded=${${string//+/ }//(#b)%([[:xdigit:]](#c2))/${(#):-0x$match[1]}}
```

- `${var//pattern/replacement}`: ksh-style parameter expansion operator to expand to the value of `$var` with every string matching `pattern` replaced with `replacement`.
- `(#b)` activate back references so every part inside brackets in the pattern can be accessed as corresponding `$match[n]` in the replacement.
- `(#c2)`: equivalent of ERE `{2}`
- `${(#)param-expansion}`: parameter expansion where the `#` flag causes the result to be interpreted as an arithmetic expression and the corresponding byte value to be returned.
- `${var:-value}`: expands to `value` if `$var` is empty, here applied to no variable at all, so we can just specify an arbitrary string as the subject of a parameter expansion.

To make it a function that decodes the contents of a variable in-place:

```
uridecode_var() {
  emulate -L zsh
  set -o extendedglob +o multibyte
  eval $1='${${'$1'//+/ }//(#b)%([[:xdigit:]](#c2))/${(#):-0x$match[1]}}'
}
```

```
$ string='Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Macintosh%3B%20U%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010.6%3B%20en'
$ uridecode_var string
$ print -r -- $string
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en
```

Comment: I'm running zsh. This worked for me and is much faster than the python solutions. (Unfortunately, most of the bash solutions don't work in zsh.) I'm going to try to adjust this so it doesn't replace the variable in-place, but instead takes the input string and returns the decoded output.

Comment: Ah: changing the eval line to `eval echo` instead of `eval $1-` merely ouputs the decoded string, rather than change the variable in-place.

Comment: @Dannid, a function that decodes its argument and prints the result on stdout would just be `decode() print -r -- ${${1//+/ }//(#b)%([[:xdigit:]](#c2))/${(#):-0x$match[1]}}` (used as `decode $var`). No need for `eval` (you'll still need the `extendedglob` and `nomultibyte` though)

Comment: Yes, thanks @stephane-chazelas - that worked, and in my .zshrc it looks like `function decode() {
  set -o extendedglob +o multibyte
  print -r -- ${${1//+/ }//(#b)%([[:xdigit:]](#c2))/${(#):-0x$match[1]}}
}`

Answer (score 2):

python, for zshrc

```
# Usage: decodeUrl %3A%2F%2F
function decodeUrl(){
    echo "$1" | python3 -c "import sys; from urllib.parse import unquote; print(unquote(sys.stdin.read()));"    
}

# Usage: encodeUrl https://google.com/search?q=urldecode+bash
#          return: https://google.com/search\?q\=urldecode+bash
function encodeUrl(){
    echo "$1" | python3 -c "import sys; from urllib.parse import quote; print(quote(sys.stdin.read()));"
}
```

Comment: In my own codes somehow I have "quote_plus" / "unquote_plus" instead - do you think the difference is significant ?

Comment: You might add `end=''` param to get rid of extra newlines `print(unquote(sys.stdin.read()),end='')` and `echo -n "$1"`.

Answer (score 1):

used gridsite-clients

```
1. yum install gridsite-clients / or apt-get install gridsite-clients
2. grep -a 'http' access.log | xargs urlencode -d
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is done in pure bash where input and output are bash variables. It will decode '+' as a space and handle the '%20' space, as well as other %-encoded characters.

```
#!/bin/bash
#here is text that contains both '+' for spaces and a %20
text="hello+space+1%202"
decoded=$(echo -e `echo $text | sed 's/+/ /g;s/%/\\\\x/g;'`)
echo decoded=$decoded
```

Comment: `sed` is not pure Bash; this spawns another process.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37840948/8142470

to work with HTML entities

> $ htmldecode() { : "${*//+/ }"; echo -e "${_//&#x/\x}" | tr -d
>   ';'; }
>   $ htmldecode
>   "http&#x3A;&#x2F;&#x2F;google.com&#x2F;search&&#x3F;q&#x3D;urldecode&#x2B;bash" http://google.com/search&?q=urldecode+bash

(argument must be quoted)

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick hint for other who are searching for a busybox compatible solution. In busybox shell you can use

```sh
httpd -d $ENCODED_URL
```

---

Example use case for busybox:

Download a file with wget and save it with the original decoded filename:

```sh
wget --no-check-certificate $ENCODED_URL -O $(basename $(httpd -d $ENCODED_URL))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer `gawk`, there's absolutely no need to force `LC_ALL=C` or `gawk -b` just to decode `URL-encoded` -

here's a fully functional proof-of-concept showcasing how `gawk-unicode` mode could directly decode purely binary files like `MP3`-audio or `MP4`-video files that were `URL-encoded`,and get back the exact same file, as confirmed by hashing.

It uses `FS | OFS` to handle the spaces that were set to `+`, similar to `python3`'s `quote-plus` in their `urllib` :

```
( fg && fg && fg ) 2>/dev/null; 
gls8x "${f}"
echo
pvE0 < "${f}" | xxh128sum | lgp3
echo ; echo
pvE0 < "${f}" | urlencodeAWKchk \
\
| gawk -ne '
  BEGIN { 
     RS="[%][[:xdigit:]]{2}"; 
     FS="[+]"
       _=(4^5)*54  # if this offset doesn-t 
                   # work, try
                   #           8^7 
                   #               instead
  
  } (NF+="_"*(ORS = sprintf("%.*s", RT != "",
                    sprintf("%c",\
                         _+("0x"  \     
                            substr( RT, 2 ))))))~""' |pvE9|xxh128sum|lgp3

  1 -rwxrwxrwx 1 5555 staff 9290187 May 27  2021 genieaudio_16277926_.lossless.mp3*
   

      in0: 8.86MiB 0:00:00 [3.56GiB/s] [3.56GiB/s][=================>] 100%            
5d43c221bf6c85abac80eea8dbb412a1  stdin


      in0: 8.86MiB 0:00:00 [3.47GiB/s] [3.47GiB/s] [=================>] 100%            
     out9: 8.86MiB 0:00:05 [1.72MiB/s] [1.72MiB/s] [ <=>  ]

5d43c221bf6c85abac80eea8dbb412a1  stdin


     1  -rw-r--r-- 1 5555 staff 215098877 Feb  8 17:30 vg3.mp4


      in0:  205MiB 0:00:00 [2.66GiB/s] [2.66GiB/s] [=================>] 100% 
          
2778670450b08cee694dcefc23cd4d93  stdin


      in0:  205MiB 0:00:00 [3.31GiB/s] [3.31GiB/s] [=================>] 100%            
     out9:  205MiB 0:02:01 [1.69MiB/s] [1.69MiB/s] [ <=> ]
2778670450b08cee694dcefc23cd4d93  stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

### Minimalistic `uridecode [-v varname]` [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) function:

Comming late on this SO Question (11 year ago), I see:

- First answer suggesting the use of `printf -v varname %b...` was offer by [jamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24003150/1765658), near than 3 year after question was asked.
- Fist answer offering a `function` for doing this was offered 10 years and 6 month after question, by [Robin A. Meade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70560850/1765658).

#### Here is my *smaller* function:

```
uridecode() {
    if [[ $1 == -v ]];then local -n _res="$2"; shift 2; else local _res; fi
    : "${*//+/ }"; printf -v _res %b "${_//%/\\x}"
    [[ ${_res@A} == _res=* ]] && echo "$_res"
}
```

Or less condensed:

```
uridecode() {
    if [[ $1 == -v ]];then           # If 1st argument is ``-v''
        local -n _res="$2"           # _res is a nameref to ``$2''
        shift 2                      # drop 1st two arguments
    else
        local _res                   # _res is a local variable
    fi
    : "${*//+/ }"                    # _ hold argumenrs having ``+'' replaced by spaces
    printf -v _res %b "${_//%/\\x}"  # store in _res rendered string
    [[ ${_res@A} == _res=* ]] &&     # print _res if local
        echo "$_res"
}
```

Usage:

```
uridecode Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Macintosh%3B%20U%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010.6%3B%20en
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en

uridecode -v myvar Hell%6f w%6Frld%21
echo $myvar 
Hello world!
```

As I use `$*` instead of `$1`, and because URI doesn't hold special characters, there is no need to **quote** arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my modified version for you:

#### source code

File ***urldecode.sh*** :

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env -S bash -euo pipefail

# @author : Unregistered Guest (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6470696/guest)
# @author : netDesign8 (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988310/netdesign8)
# @license : CC BY-SA 4.0
# @see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37840948
# @modified
urldecode() {
  : "${*//%/\\x}"
  printf '%b' "${_}"
}
urldecode_plus() {
  : "${*//+/ }"
  : "${_//%/\\x}"
  printf '%b' "${_}"
}
urldecode_restfull() {
  : "${*// /+}"
  : "${_//%20/+}"
  : "${_//%/\\x}"
  printf '%b' "${_}"
}

# @author : Jay (https://stackoverflow.com/users/448081/jay)
# @author : Rory O'Kane (https://stackoverflow.com/users/578288/rory-okane)
# @license : CC BY-SA 4.0
# @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21693459
# @modified
urldecode_py3() {
  python3 \
    -c \
    "import sys; from urllib.parse import unquote; print(unquote(sys.stdin.read()));" \
    <<< "${*}"
}
urldecode_plus_py3() {
  python3 \
    -c \
    "import sys; from urllib.parse import unquote_plus; print(unquote_plus(sys.stdin.read()));" \
    <<< "${*}"
}
urldecode_py2() {
  #XXX Python 2.x deprecated
  >&2 echo 'warning: Python 2.x deprecated!'
  python2 \
    -c \
    "import sys, urllib as ul; print ul.unquote(sys.stdin.read());" \
    <<< "${*}"
}
urldecode_plus_py2() {
  #XXX Python 2.x deprecated
  >&2 echo 'warning: Python 2.x deprecated!'
  python2 \
    -c \
    "import sys, urllib as ul; print ul.unquote_plus(sys.stdin.read());" \
    <<< "${*}"
}
```

#### testing

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env -S bash -euo pipefail

echo ===============

source urldecode.sh

url='https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fgo/sss+kkk/hjo%20kop/kk jj/search%3Fq%3Dko%20ddd fff+urldecode%2Bbash'

echo

echo -----bash
urldecode "${url}" "${url}"

echo

echo -----bash plus
urldecode_plus "${url}" "${url}"

echo

echo -----bash restfull
urldecode_restfull "${url}" "${url}"

echo

echo -----py3
urldecode_py3 "${url}" "${url}"

echo

echo -----py3 plus
urldecode_plus_py3 "${url}" "${url}"

echo

echo -----py2
urldecode_py2 "${url}" "${url}"

echo

echo -----py2 plus
urldecode_plus_py2 "${url}" "${url}"

echo
```

Answer (score -1):

A slightly modified version of the Python answer that accepts an input and output file in a one liner.

```
cat inputfile.txt | python -c "import sys, urllib as ul; print ul.unquote(sys.stdin.read());" > ouputfile.txt
```

Answer (score -4):

```
$ uenc='H%C3%B6he %C3%BCber%20dem%20Meeresspiegel'
$ utf8=$(printf "${uenc//%/\\x}")
$ echo $utf8
Höhe über dem Meeresspiegel
$
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.