# Convert percent-encoded file URL to local file in bash

Tags: bash, url

I have a percent encoded file URL - for example `file:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt`. I need to convert it to a local file - `/home/sashoalm/Has Spaces.txt`.

How can I do that in bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In BASH you can use this utility function:

```
decodeURL() {
   printf "$(sed 's#^file://##;s/+/ /g;s/%\(..\)/\\x\1/g;' <<< "$@")\n";
}
```

**Then call this function as:**

```
decodeURL 'file:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt'
/home/sashoalm/Has Spaces.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

[Urlencode](http://linux.die.net/man/1/urlencode) should do it (-d option)

> -d Do URL-decoding rather than encoding, according to RFC 1738. %HH and %hh strings are converted and other characters are passed through
>   unmodified, with the exception that + is converted to space.

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue:

```
echo file:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt |\
  perl -MURI -MURI::Escape -lne \
      'print uri_unescape(URI->new($_)->path)'
```

See [URI](http://p3rl.org/URI) and [URI::Escape](http://p3rl.org/URI::Escape).

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk

```perl
#!/usr/bin/awk -fn
@include "ord"
BEGIN {
  RS = "%.."
}
{
  printf RT ? $0 chr("0x" substr(RT, 2)) : $0
}
```

Or

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -niord '{printf RT?$0chr("0x"substr(RT,2)):$0}' RS=%..
```

[How to decode URL-encoded string in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6250698/#14000368)

Answer (score 1):

Using GIO binary for different locales (Bulgarian for example):

```
LC_MESSAGES=C gio info file:///home/user/%D0%9D%D0%90%20%D0%91%D0%AA%D0%9B%D0%93%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%98|grep "local path:"|sed 's/^[^/]*//'
```

Result (localized):

```
/home/user/НА БЪЛГАРСКИ
```