# Using curl the SCOM rest api returns "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: curl, scom

I am trying to retrieve SCOM alerts using their REST API via curl.  It keeps returning:

```
"errorMessage": "Index was outside the bounds of the array.",
"errorTrace": "   at Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OMDataService.Filters.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n...
```

First, I took my:

```
AuthenticationMode:<domain>\<username>:<password>
```

string and converted it to UTF8 and then used openssl to base64 encode that.  I took that "token" and used it in my /OperationsManager/authenticate call like so:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://myhostname/OperationsManager/authenticate' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
--data-raw '"<my_base64_encoded_token>"'
```

This returns me a "SCOMSessionId" and "SCOM-CSRF-TOKEN".  I then take the "SCOM-CSRF-TOKEN" and make the following call to /OperationsManager/data/alert:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://myhostname/OperationsManager/data/alert' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
--header 'SCOM-CSRF-TOKEN:<csrf_token_value_here>' \
--data-raw '{
    "criteria":"(ResolutionState = '\''0'\'')",
    "displayColumns": [
        "severity","monitoringobjectdisplayname","name","age","repeatcount"
    ]
}'
```

What could I be doing wrong?  All the documentation I find is centered around powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SCOM-CSRF-TOKEN needs to be decoded. I know it doesn't tell you this anywhere in the docs.

Using a site such as https://www.urldecoder.org/ will work, or if you are looking to do it programmatically you can use something like URI.decode(<your_token_value>) in ruby, for instance. There is this answer for just doing it in bash as well [How to decode URL-encoded string in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250698/how-to-decode-url-encoded-string-in-shell)