# Bash, not all strings in a text are url decoded

Tags: bash, urldecode

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37840948/1048678) I wrote a small script to get the decoded output of a text file that has some url encoded strings.

```
function urldecode() { : "${*//+/ }"; echo -e "${_//%/\\x}"; }
input="temp.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  eval urldecode "$line"
done < "$input"
```

The problem I found was that while the string `foo%20bar` was decoded as `foo bar`, `http%3A%2F%2F`was not decoded.  Both of them appear in several lines.

I tried executing single file lines from Terminal and all went good.

Comment: Where does the `eval` come from?

Comment: The `eval` is unnecessary, and potentially dangerous.  The example works fine for me.  I guess that you may have some unusual characters in your `temp.txt` file (e.g. something that looks like a `%`).  Check the output of `cat -et temp.txt`.

Comment: what are you expecting as the output for `http%3A%2F%2F`? I get `http://`

Comment: Whehn I run `urldecode http%3A%2F%2F`, I get on standard output `http://`. The function is fine (try it!), but I don't understand how you script is being used; and of course  the `eval` silly.