# Sanitizing read entry in Bash

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I have a script which prompts for user credentials in order to phrase a curl command. The issue I am having is if the password has a special character it can mess up the curl command.

example code:

> curl -k -o ~/Desktop/output.txt
>   https://$name:$password@'server.example.com/serverpage.asp?action=MakeList&User='$enduser

example inputs

name:test

password:P@55w0rd!

output:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 55w0rd!@server.example.com; nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I understand that the curl command is hitting the "@" in the password and trying to connect to 55w0rd!@server.example.com in stead of server.example.com.

How do I "sanitize" the input to escape special characters?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the "-u" parameter for curl. On the other hand try to use " for start and end the parameters and finally use ${varname} format to access to variables to prevent bash escaping problems.

```
curl -k -u "${name}:${password}" -o "~/Desktop/output.txt" "https://server.example.com/serverpage.asp?action=MakeList&User=${enduser}"
```

Comment: No? -> curl -k -u "${name}:${password}" -o "~/Desktop/output.txt" "https://server.example.com/serverpage.asp?action=MakeList&User=${enduser}"

Comment: Actually, yes, sorry. I missed the -u. I'd really like to upvote, but apparently you need to edit the answer before I can do that. Maybe add the content of your comment?

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work for me. using -u causes curl to attempt two downloads in this case. I'm not sure why....

Answer (score 1):

You want to urlencode your password (`Pp%340ssword!`). AFAIK there is no simple way to do it in bash, this [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/urlencode-from-a-bash-script) has some suggestions involving Perl etc. Testing or looking at the curl source might reveal that just replacing `@` with `%40` is sufficient, I haven't tried for the general case.

Comment: I verified that typing in "P%4055w0rd!" does work with my original syntax. looks like I'll have to awk/sed the password first. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -k -o ~/Desktop/output.txt "https://${name}:${password}@server.example.com/serverpage.asp?action=MakeList&User=${enduser}"
```