# URL encoding a string in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, wget, urlencode

I am writing a bash script in where I am trying to submit a post variable, however wget is treating it as multiple URLS I believe because it is not URLENCODED... here is my basic thought

```
MESSAGE='I am trying to post this information'
wget -O test.txt http://xxxxxxxxx.com/alert.php --post-data 'key=xxxx&message='$MESSAGE''
```

I am getting errors and the alert.php is not getting the post variable plus it pretty mush is saying

can't resolve I
can't resolve am
can't resolve trying
.. and so on.

My example above is a simple kinda sudo example but I believe if I can url encode it, it would pass, I even tried php like:

```
MESSAGE='I am trying to post this information'
MESSAGE=$(php -r 'echo urlencode("'$MESSAGE'");')
```

but php errors out.. any ideas? How can i pass the variable in $MESSAGE without php executing it?

Comment: Look for my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67448946/10534012).

Comment: I'm using `jq` for that, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34407620/906265 e.g. `printf %s "k=$SOMEVAL"|jq -sRr @uri`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `$MESSAGE` to be in double-quotes, so the shell won't split it into separate words, then pass it to PHP as an argument:

```sh
ENCODEDMESSAGE="$(php -r 'echo rawurlencode($argv[1]);' -- "$MESSAGE")"
```

Answer (score 18):

On CentOS, no extra package needed:

```
python -c "import urllib;print urllib.quote(raw_input())" <<< "$message"
```

Comment: This solution is python 2 only

Comment: Python 3 version looks like `python3 -c "import urllib.parse; print(urllib.parse.quote(input())"`.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs you forgot one closing brace :)

Comment: A correct Python 3 version looks like `python3 -c "import urllib.parse; print(urllib.parse.quote(input()))"` (tested this time).

Comment: Python version agnostic: `python -c $'try: import urllib.request as urllib\nexcept: import urllib\nimport sys\nsys.stdout.write(urllib.quote(input()))' <<< "$message"` and adds no `\n`

Answer (score 6):

Extending [Rockallite's very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42131272/5794048) for Python 3 and multiline input from a file (this time on Ubuntu, but that shouldn't matter):

```
cat any.txt | python3 -c "import urllib.parse, sys; print(urllib.parse.quote(sys.stdin.read()))"
```

This will result in all lines from the file concatenated into a single URL, the newlines being replaced by `%0A`.

Comment: No this doesn't work.  Replace `sys.stdin.read()` with `input()` instead. 
Using the `read()` adds `%0A` which is file termination character.

Comment: Using `input()` would only return the first line, but my intention was to get all lines from the file, encoded in one URL. You could easily convert `%0A` to newline again if necessary: `[...] | sed "s/%0A/\n/g"`.

Comment: Works for me as posted by @Murphy (28/01/2020)