# URL encoding a string in shell script in a portable way

Tags: linux, shell, posix, urlencode

I need to URL encode a string using a shell function that will run in BusyBox Ash, Dash, Bash and ZSH.

It will run in different Docker containers, so it'd be good to have as little dependencies to install as possible.

Notes:

- The question "[URL encoding a string in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876353/url-encoding-a-string-in-bash-script)" asks for a Bash-specific script, and the only provided answer depends on PHP being installed on the container.
- The question "[How to urlencode data for curl command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command)" is specific to *curl*, but is certainly open to non-specific answers. However, none of the 25 answers seem to apply. One of the answers there only works to send data to **curl**, while some are specific to **bash** or **ksh**, some others require **Perl**, **PHP**, **Python**, **Lua**, **NodeJS**, **Ruby**, **[gridsite-clients](https://packages.debian.org/sid/net/gridsite-clients)**, **uni2ascii**, **jq**, **awk** or **sed** to be installed. One of them doesn't require additional dependencies, but doesn't preserve characters like `a`, `1` and `~`.

What I'd expect to have:

```
$> urlencode '/'
%2f

$> urlencode 'ç'
%c3%a7

$> urlencode '*'
%2a

$> urlencode abc-123~6
abc-123~6

$> urlencode 'a test ?*ç '
a%20test%20%3f%2a%c3%a7%20
```

Comment: seems to be duplicate look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functions below have been tested in **BusyBox Ash**, **Dash**, **Bash** and **ZSH**.

They only use shell builtins or core commands and should work in other shells as well.

```
urlencodepipe() {
  local LANG=C; local c; while IFS= read -r c; do
    case $c in [a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]) printf "$c"; continue ;; esac
    printf "$c" | od -An -tx1 | tr ' ' % | tr -d '\n'
  done <<EOF
$(fold -w1)
EOF
  echo
}

urlencode() { printf "$*" | urlencodepipe ;}
```

How it works:

- Standard input is processed by `fold -w1`, which *re-formats* its input so that it is 1 column wide (in other words, it adds a `\n` after each input character so that each character will be on its own line)
- The here-document `<<EOF` feeds the output of `fold` to the `read` command
- The `while` command accepts one line at a time (which is only 1 character wide) from the `read` command, which gets its input from `fold`, and assigns it to variable `c`
- `case` tests if that character needs to be url encoded. If it doesn't, then it's printed and the while loop continues
- [od](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html) converts each input character to hex
- `tr` converts spaces to `%` and joins multiple lines

Comment: Nice, though it's not perfectly portable, as the output from `od` varies from what you expect in non-Linux environments.  For me, `urlencode ' '` returns `%%%%%%%%%%%20%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%`. Replacing the first `tr` with `sed 's/  */%/g;s/%$//'` seems to help, but it still fails to translate `\n` to `%0d`.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work in ZSH on macOS (as @ghoti illustrates above).