# How to copy file with ^ in name?

Tags: bash, shell, hdfs, urlencode

I'm trying to copy a file with a ^ in the file name and getting error.

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/BC10^Dummy* /user/app
```

I'm getting below error:

```
copyFromLocal: unexpected URISyntaxException
```

I suspect the `^` is causing the error but it's not a space so how do I get around this issue? I can't rename the file, that's not an option.

Comment: This might help: [URL encoding a string in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11876353/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `^` as `%5E`

`/tmp/BC10^Dummy*` --> `/tmp/BC10%5EDummy*`

Try below command :

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/BC10%5EDummy* /user/app
```

Comment: The %5E worked but I'm facing a different error now. ```copyFromLocal: `/tmp/GC10^Dummy*': No such file or directory``` I can see the quotes seem different. But how do I correc that? The code in Python is: ```subprocess.call(["hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /tmp/GC10%5EDummy* /user/app"], shell=True)```