# Urlencode a multiline string in VIM, so it can be used to query a search engine

Tags: search, vim, artificial-intelligence, urlencode

In Vim, it would be cool to search for the currently highlighted text in a search engine of your choice. Especially with all the AI search engines that are appearing on the scene.

This kinda works, but the text is not urlencoded:

```
:'<,'>y|call system('firefox https://www.gnod.com/search/ai?q='.shellescape(@*))
```

I wonder if there is a way to urlencode it?

Comment: https://www.danielbigham.ca/cgi-bin/document.pl?mode=Display&DocumentID=1053 , https://gist.github.com/atripes/15372281209daf5678cded1d410e6c16 Found in https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=vim+encode+url

Comment: Other options that can probably be plugged in can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command (from second answer onwards) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876353/url-encoding-a-string-in-bash-script.

Comment: @phd: I hope to keep it a slick oneliner and avoid to use a massive script like those that can be found via Google.

Comment: @Marijn: Yes, passing it to curl or jq could be a good option. But how do you pass a multiline string to a shell command?

Comment: There is no native `urlencode()` function but Tim Pope has [this](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/master/plugin/unimpaired.vim#L460-L463) in a plugin of his.

Comment: @romainl: Holy moly, this works!

:'<,'>y|call system('firefox https://www.gnod.com/search/ai?q='.substitute(iconv(@*, 'latin1', 'utf-8'),'[^A-Za-z0-9_.~-]','\="%".printf("%02X",char2nr(submatch(0)))','g'))

Comment: Yeah, but that's one hell of one-liner.

Comment: @romainl Yup, but maybe thats the shortest possible.

Comment: @no_gravity you should post an answer if you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
:'<,'>y|call system('firefox gnod.com/search/ai?q='.substitute(iconv(@*, 'latin1', 'utf-8'),'[^A-Za-z0-9_.~-]','\="%".printf("%02X",char2nr(submatch(0)))','g'))
```

Comment: How about explaining *how* it works?