# Applescript: Open location with multiple words not working

Tags: applescript

I am trying to make a script that will do a google search for you, but if i do a multiple word search, it doesn't work. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
set keyword to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Search Query" default answer "")
display dialog "Enter Search Query" buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button 2
if the button returned of the result is "Ok" then
    open location "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" & keyword
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to account for the space and convert it/them to  "%20"

```
set aSpace to "%20"
    display dialog "Enter Search Query" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button 2
    copy the result as list to {text_returned, button_pressed}
    set t to words of text_returned

    if the button_pressed is "Ok" then

        open location "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" & encode(text_returned, space, aSpace)
    end if

    on encode(x, y, z)
        tid(y)
        set x to text items of x
        tid(z)
        return x as string
    end encode

    on tid(x)
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to x
    end tid
```

The encoding code is from [here](http://www.mentby.com/Group/applescript-users/how-to-convert-space-to-20.html)

Comment: When I run it, it says it expected the "on" in "on encode and on tid" to be else

Comment: Hi, That does not really make sense. Can you post the full error. The script works fine here. No errors. Did you change the script I posted. If so how?

Comment: Nevermind. All I had to do was specify a browser. Thanks!    `set keyword to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Search Query" default answer "")  
display dialog "Enter Search Query" buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button 2  
if the button returned of the result is "Ok" then  
open location "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" & keyword  
end if`

Answer (score 0):

You also have to escape special characters like % and &. And `open location` doesn't work with URLs that have some non-ASCII characters:

```
open location "http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/漢字"
```

You can [url encode using a shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/urlencode-from-a-bash-script) though:

`do shell script "open http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape(ARGV[0])' " & quoted form of "字%'\\&" & ")"`

Answer (score 0):

You have two dialogs opening when you can have only one :

```
set myDialog to display dialog "Enter Search Query" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button 2
set keyword to text returned of myDialog
if the button returned of myDialog is "Ok" then open location "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" & keyword
```

I don't see what you mean  with you multiple search no working.
For me it works just fine if you enter in the dialog box multiple words separed by spaces.