# quotes in bash argument fail with curl

Tags: bash, curl, double-quotes

I would like to log various things when calling functions in a bash script and so I am trying to have a special place to do this

```
function CallAndLog {
  echo "$@" > /tmp/debug
  res=$("$@" 2> /tmp/error)
  if [ $? -gt 0 ]
  then
    echo "error : $(</tmp/error)" >> /tmp/log
  fi
  echo "$res" >> /tmp/log
}

val="a test"
CallAndLog curl --data '"'"query=$val"'"' http://google.com
```

I get this

- /tmp/debug

curl --data "query=a test" http://google.com

- /tmp/error

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'test"'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   967  100   959  100     8   1060      8  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  1572

- /tmp/log

`<!DOCTYPE html>...`

/tmp/debug is perfect, this is exactly what I want to execute, and if I copy and paste that it works. However the error suggests that "a" and "test" were split into 2 and curl tried "test" as the url. This is what I don't understand

I have tried LOTS of different things : $*, $@, "$*", "*@", various ways to put the single and double quotes, so after hours of struggling I call for your help !!! Many Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [URLEncode from a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/urlencode-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: I don't see how you get `http://google.com` in debug

Comment: Since "http://google.com" never appears in your example, the debug/log output cannot correspond to the input you show. It's impossible to know if the rest of the input corresponds, but I am sceptical since the example should fail in a different way. The output looks like it comes from `CallAndLog curl --data '"'query=$val'"' http://google.com`

Comment: @glennjackman I don't think it is a duplicate as there is something fishy with the $@ or $* and the quotes. url encode might be a way to get around there but I won't know why it was failing

Answer (score 1):

You're executing correctly, but logging incorrectly. That why the log appears fine while the command fails.

Invocation should be simply

```
CallAndLog curl --data "query=$val"
```

To log the statement, use

```
printf "%q " "$@" >> /tmp/debug
```

Your quoting will be reformatted, but will be semantically identical (i.e. you can copy-paste the statement to run the same command the same way). This is due to the fact that quoting is shell syntax that controls various forms of splitting and expansion, and only the effects (and not the syntax) is carried into the function.

---

Here is an example:

```
function CallAndLog {
  printf "%q " "$@" > /tmp/debug
  echo >> /tmp/debug # add line feed
  res=$("$@" 2> /tmp/error)
  if [ $? -gt 0 ]
  then
    echo "error : $(</tmp/error)" >> /tmp/log
  fi
  echo "$res" >> /tmp/log
}

val="a test"
CallAndLog curl --data "query=$val" http://google.com
```

After running that, we can look at the output log files:

```
$ cat /tmp/debug
curl --data query=a\ test http://google.com 

$ cat /tmp/error
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   971  100   959  100    12   6101     76 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 43590

$ cat /tmp/log
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, ...
```

Comment: If you do CallAndLog 'curl ..."query=$val"', $val will not be replaced by its value since it is single quoted

Comment: I haven't tested your log statement yet but I can tell you I am not executing correctly (see /tmp/error)

Comment: @Thomas it would be replaced by its value upon `eval`uation

Comment: @Thomas No, I meant that your execution line in CallAndLog is correct, but your invocation of CallAndLog is wrong because you try to please the incorrect log statement rather than the correct execution line. The answer shows how to  invoke it correctly.

Comment: I have tried that but itdoesn't get replaced, it stays as $val

Comment: @Thomas Ok, I see that the two different approaches in the answer were confusing. I deleted the last one so no one will be tempted to copy commands without reading the context. Try again now.

Comment: @Thomas Please be careful to read the post in its entirety and use quotes exactly as shown. I posted an example showing it works as advertised. If you get a different result, please post the code you're using and the errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

As you've guessed, the problem lies in `res=$("$@" 2> /tmp/error)`.  When executing your sample curl statement the quotes are being lost, so what is actually being passed is:

```
curl --data query=a test http://google.com
```

So, how do we fix this?  Well, I think the easiest way is to modify how you're calling your statement:

```
val="a test"
CallAndLog curl --data query=\"${val}\"
```

By escaping the quotes, we *should* now be sending in the proper syntax:

```
curl --data query="a test" http://google.com
```

**This code works locally**

```
~/tmp › cat /tmp/debug 
curl --data query="a test" http://google.com

~/tmp › cat /tmp/log 
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=en>   <meta charset=utf-8>   <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">   <title>Error 405 (Method Not Allowed)!!1</title>   <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}} </style>   <a href=//www.google.com/><img src=//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm.gif alt=Google></a>   <p><b>405.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>   <p>The request method <code>POST</code> is inappropriate for the URL <code>/</code>.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Now, the error result coming back from Google is another problem altogether.

Comment: I don't believe this analysis is correct. `"$@"` will preserve word-separation in the arguments. Furthermore, OP does *not* want to pass actual double-quotes to curl, afaik.

Comment: True, but "$@" preserves word-separation only until the point that it's being sent into `$()`, that's when it loses them in this example.

Comment: Not so. `(set -- bash -c echo\ \"\$1\" _ "a b" c; res=$("$@"); echo "$res")`

Comment: It's clear from the OP that it's losing the inner quotes around `"a test"`

Comment: what inner quotes around "a test"? `val="a test"` does not put any quotes into `$val`. (And they are not being expected by curl, either. The correct invocation is `--data query=a%20test`). You certainly don't want `--data \"query=a%20test\"`. TIAS.

Comment: :sigh: you **do** want `--data query="a test"`, the _inner_ quotes are the ones around `"a test"` that are being passed in via the call to `CallAndLog`.  Replacing the space with `%20` simply does the same thing.  Try it locally.

Comment: I did. Did you? Replacing the space with %20 definitely doesn't do "the same thing": you need to be aware of who is dequoting what when. Your way will actually send the double quotes to the web server, as well as a literal space. (http://google.com will reject a url with a space in it, as it should: it's your responsibility to urlencode.)

Comment: works for me, even though there are still some problems if I do -- data \"q1=${val1}&q2=${val2}\" (but curl accepts multiple --data so will do)

Comment: Any idea why my code was failing in the first place ? Copy and paste is cool but I would like to learn something from that :)

Comment: Yes, as I said (and have been incorrectly questioned on) is that you were losing the quotes around `a test` when you passed it into the sub-shell.  The escaped quotes in the call prevent that behavior.

Comment: As others have pointed out, a space is not valid in Google's query syntax, but the code above solves the OP question.

Comment: Right, I am not looking to send this to google.com it was just an example.

Comment: @Donovan The result in /tmp/debug is : curl --data "query=a test" http://google.com. At what point was I losing the quotes ? I had some '"' in my call to get them

Comment: @Thomas as I specified in my original answer; you're losing them when you pass them into the sub-shell created by `res=$("$@" 2> /tmp/error)`

Comment: @Donovan so why were they in /tmp/debug ? (sorry for being annoying here but I want to get to the bottom of this)

Comment: They weren't.  If you look again, you'll see `"query=a test"` -- there are no quotes around `"a test"`, yes?  In the example I posted in my answer, you'll see `query="a test"`.  See the difference?

Comment: if you need quotes around the entire string, you can easily add that.