# How to pass a JSON in url via cURL?

Tags: json, curl, get, curl-commandline

I want to do something like following:

```
curl localhost:8080/myapp/?params={"first_key":"I'm the first value","second_key":"the second value"}
```

This is working pretty normal when I am trying to access the page via browser, but it does not work via cURL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to urlencode data for curl command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is caused by cURL's "URL globbing parser" (see the [docs](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)):

> You can specify multiple URLs or parts of URLs by writing part sets within braces as in:
>
> http://{one,two,three}.com

So your command is being expanded to:

```
curl localhost:8080/myapp/?params="first_key":"I'm the first value"
curl localhost:8080/myapp/?params="second_key":"the second value"
```

You need to use the `-g` option (or `--globoff`):

> This option switches off the "URL globbing parser". When you set this option, you can specify URLs that contain the letters {}[] without having them being interpreted by curl itself.

So:

```
curl -g localhost:8080/myapp/?params={"first_key":"I'm the first value","second_key":"the second value"}
```

Then, to preserve the double quotes, you need to wrap the URL in single quotes:

```
curl -g 'localhost:8080/myapp/?params={"first_key":"I'\''m the first value","second_key":"the second value"}'
```