# unix utilities to replace certain characters

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to get into UNIX. I want to replace and `-`, `?`, `:`, `/`, `&` to become `%5f`, `%3f` `%3a`, `%2f`, `%26`, `%20` (these are the hexadecimal digits corresponding to the ASCII code).

I am also trying to make any lower case characters become upper case and vice versa, e.g. `the rock` to become `THE ROCK` and `THE ROCK` to become `the rock`.

I am trying to do this all using standard UNIX utilities commands using a script, ideally all on one line.

So far I have got

```
tr A-Z a-z
```

but not sure how to make the `?` and the other ones spit out the corresponding hex #s.

Comment: The hexadecimal conversion you're talking about is [url encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and for that you should check [urlencode-from-a-bash-script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/urlencode-from-a-bash-script) for several ideas.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make upper case to lower case and vise versa. like Hey TherE
>   becomes hEY tHERe.

`tr` can do that:

```
$ echo Hey TherE | tr '[a-zA-Z]' '[A-Za-z]'
hEY tHERe
```

`tr` does translations and, in the above, translates lower case to upper case and vice versa.

As for replacing some characters with there hex value, here is a brute force method using `sed`:

```
$ echo "and-or?" | sed 's/-/%2d/g; s/?/%3f/g; s/:/%3a/g; s|/|%2f|g; s/&/%26/g; s/ /%20/g'
and%2dor%3f
```

Comment: woahh!!! what does the and or do? and shouldnt there be spaces between 'and5' and 'for'?

Comment: @user3563184 The string `and-or?` was just an example of input that contained two of your special characters: `-` and `?`.  If you want `and-or?` to be converted to something else, let me know.

Comment: I think im confused of what is going on. If I actually run that what will happen? I got a mismatched error. I guess im not sure what and-or actually is

Comment: @user3563184  The `$` is the command prompt.  Your prompt may be longer but they usually end with `$`.  `echo "and-or?"` creates sample input.  Replace the string in quotes with whatever you want.  The `sed...` part does the conversion.  After running the command on the first line, the second line should appear as the output.  (Let me know if I missed the point of your question.)

Comment: Oh Sorry your right thank you so much. your awesome I just read it 100 times and got it lol

Comment: ok so I want to make upper case to lower case and vise versa. like Hey TherE becomes hEY tHERe. SO I found out that tr A-Z a-z makes it uppercase to lower case. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @user3563184 I added code for switching cases to the answer.

Comment: I see thank you.What is the and%2dor%3f for?