# Google maps JSON query

Tags: json, google-maps, curl

I am trying to do a curl request to a google maps API using the following URL. When I do it from the browser I get back the right results but if I do it from a command line on the same machine I get an error (see below). What am I missing?

Curl request:

```
curl https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=San+Francisco,CA&destination=Mountain+View,CA&sensor=false&key=API_KEY
```

Output:

```
{
  "error_message" : "Invalid request. Missing the 'destination' parameter.",
  "routes" : [],
  "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Comment: Are you URL encoding the URL as described in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview#BuildingURLs)?

Comment: If the URL works as is from the browser shouldnt the same URL passed to curl work too?

Comment: related question: [How to urlencode data for curl command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the ampercent `&` sign - you're actually breaking your command line. To fix it, type your URL between double quotes `"<url>"`:

```
curl "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=San+Francisco,CA&destination=Mountain+View,CA&sensor=false&key=API_KEY"
```