# Curl command line encoding of query parameters for an HTTP PUT

Tags: web-services, rest, http, unix, curl

I have multiple query parameters that I want to send in an HTTP PUT operation using curl. How do I encode the query parameters?  Example:

```
$ curl -X PUT http://example.com/resource/1?param1=value%201&param2=value2
```

If 'value 1' contains spaces or other characters that are interpreted by the shell, the command will not parse correctly.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The solution is to use the `-G` switch in combination with the `--data-urlencode` switch. Using the original example, the command would look like the following:

```
$ curl -X PUT -G 'http://example.com/resource/1' --data-urlencode 'param1=value 1' --data-urlencode param2=value2
```

The `-G` switch causes the parameters encoded with the `--data-urlencode` switches to be appended to the end of the http URL with a `?` separator.

In the example, the value of `param1`, would be encoded as `value%201`, where %20 is the encoded value for a space character.

Comment: @2Agyu what about url encoding GET query/parameters? Those that are part of url and not part of POST request?

Answer (score 0):

I was wanting to use URL-encoded query parameters **and** a body/payload (in my case, a JSON). It seems like the only way to get curl to do this is to supply a URL which includes the encoded query string - in other words, to URL-encode the query parameters yourself.

An excellent answer to that last part was provided by Sergey and Bruno here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10797966/19632250

Putting these together into something usable, I got the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

urlEncode() {
    echo $1 | curl -Gso /dev/null -w %{url_effective} --data-urlencode @- "" | sed -E 's/..(.*).../\1/'
}

echo '{"data":"this is some test data"}' > /tmp/test

url="https://example.com/test?$(urlEncode "param1")=$(urlEncode "value 1")&$(urlEncode "param2")=$(urlEncode "value 2")"

# Payload from a file:
curl -X POST $url -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -T "/tmp/test"

# Alternative:
#curl -X POST $url -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"data":"this is some test data"}'
```

Answer (score -1):

PUT requests are actually working like POST requests.

You should use
`$ curl -X PUT --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://whatever`

Data should be `x-www-form-urlencode`d.

EDIT: Though it is totally contrary to the standard, I've seen instances where the request body must both had to be appended as a query string *and* passed as form-data.

LinkedIn API is the most notable.

Comment: It would be quite helpful if someone would elaborate on why downvoting..

Comment: Because the question is about using url parameters and your answer doesn't use those lol.

If the question was asking "how do I url encode the data/payload?" then maybe your answer would be useful, but the question says "How do I encode the query parameters?" and your answer makes no attempt to answer that question.