# curl command with queryparameter for passing urlencode

Tags: linux, curl

I have been hitting a curl command with queryparametr in the request and passing a json format in the query parameter , but I am getting error like (" some well formatted json in parameter query.unexpected character encountered parsing error while parsing value .

curl -g --request GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "apitoken:abcd" "https://odat.abc.com/api/data?query=$(echo '$jsonInput')"

jsonInput is the json format file we are passing here.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32980082/1395722

```
curl -G --request GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "apitoken:abcd" "https://odat.abc.com/api/data" --data-urlencode "query=$(echo $jsonInput)"
```

Comment: when i try this, iam getting Missing query parametr error , i think for this the query parameter should be along with endpoint with a ? .is there any other way?@a.l.

Comment: `--request GET` is superfluous in this command line

Comment: @Daniel , didnt get you

Comment: can somebody pls help me

Comment: @Deepak Would you mind to offer an right request sample, like 'GET /xxx?xx=dfdd'

Comment: @a.l. the sample i provided is the correct one which i use