# Pass json value to curl variable via CLI within Bash script

Tags: json, bash, curl

Using `GET` I need to pass a `json` value to a URL via the command line within a bash script.

This works:

```
curl -i "http://MYURL:8080/admin/rest_api/api?api=trigger_dag&dag_id=spark_submit&conf=\{\"filename\":\"myfile.csv\"\}"
```

If I want to expand on the `json` value, I would prefer to pass a variable via the URL parameter for readability. Somethig like ... but this doesn't appear to work correctly.

```
generate_post_data =
{
  "filename": "myfile.csv"    
}

curl -i "http://MYURL:8080/admin/rest_api/api?api=trigger_dag&dag_id=spark_submit&conf=${generate_post_data}"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command

Comment: Check the correct syntax for setting a string variable in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly set the variable and you should url encode it using the `--data-urlencode` option.

```
#!/bin/bash

generate_post_data="filename=myfile.csv"
curl -G "http://MYURL:8080/admin/rest_api/api?api=trigger_dag&dag_id=spark_submit" --data-urlencode $generate_post_data
```

From the manpage:

> `--data-urlencode <data>`
>
> (HTTP) This posts data, similar to the other -d, --data options with
>   the exception that this performs URL-encoding.
>
> To be CGI-compliant, the  part should begin with a name followed
>   by a separator and a content specification. The  part can be
>   passed to curl using one of the following syntaxes:

For more info you can use `man curl` and then `/data-urlencode` to jump to the section on it.