# Curl the results of a grep?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, grep

Here's how I'm grepping for lines:

```
grep "random text" /
```

I want to curl based on the text found.  This is what I've tried:

```
grep "random text" / | curl http://example.com/test.php?text=[TEXT HERE]
```

What I don't understand how to do is use the results of grep while curling.  How can I replace `[TEXT HERE]` which the results of my grep so it's getting the correct url?

Comment: `grep: /: Is a directory`

Comment: The solutions presented so far make different assumptions about what you want because you haven't been clear.  Do you want one `curl` command per line of grep result, or do you want  to send the entire grep result to a single `curl` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Passing all results from grep in one request:

```
 curl --data-urlencode "text=$(grep PATTERN file)" "http://example.com/test.php"
```

## One request per grep result:

Use a `while` loop in combination with `read`:

```
grep PATTERN file | while read -r value ; do
    curl --data-urlencode "text=${value}" "http://example.com/test.php"
done
```

Comment: The text probably needs to be url-encoded. It's also not clear that he wants to do a separate request for each matching line, or send it all as one request.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep 'random text' file | xargs -I {} curl 'http://example.com/test.php?text={}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the output of `grep` in a variable, and put that variable in place of `[TEXT HERE]`

```
output=$(grep "random text" filename)
curl "http://example.com/test.php?text=$output"
```

The quotes are important, since `?` has special meaning to the shell and `$output` might contain whitespace or wildcard characters that would otherwise be processed.

If `$output` can contain special URL characters, you need to URL-encode it. See [How to urlencode data for curl command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command) for various ways to do this.