# cUrl uncorrect symbols

Tags: curl

when sending a request I have an error

> 400 Bad request: Your browser sent an invalid
>   request.

The error is due to the encoding of Russian characters, since the command line does not process Russian characters.

> /search/physical?token=Rxb7tDa5bPwZ&region=0&firstname=Андрей&secondname=Владимирович&lastname=Лугов&birthdate=10.05.1972

How can I solve this problem? do you need to send Russian characters to execute requests?

Comment: What does this have to do with *java*? Why did you tag your question with Java? (And what's the *programming* angle? - for general questions about user applications, you can go to superuser.com)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt sorry,  tag added by mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** If you use *curl from command line*, you have to use:

```
    curl --data-urlencode
```

Like explained here: [How to urlencode data for curl command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use url formatting, for example, standard java.net.URLDecoder

```
private String decode(String s) {
    try {
        return URLDecoder.decode(s, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```