# Special characters in curl post

Tags: bash, curl, apache-nifi

I am trying to use the following curl

```
curl -k 'https://myhost.com:9091/nifi-api/access/token' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' --data "username=$USERNAME&password=$PASSWORD" --compressed —insecure
```

But get an error with a `%` in the password saying

```
URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern
```

I have seen suggestions online to use `--data-urlencode` but then I get the following error.

```
The username and password must be specified.
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried encapsulating your variables `--data "username=${USERNAME}&password=${PASSWORD}"`.  Your script could be seeing the variable as `$USERNAME&` instead of your intended `$USERNAME`.

Comment: I get the same error unfortunately. Even tried not using variables and hardcoding the username/password with the same results. The `%` is at the very end of the password if that maybe makes a difference.

Comment: No, `USERNAME&` is not a valid variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--data-urlencode` is the way to go adding it multiple times, one per parameter

```
userh='vf&re'
passwordh='asdaf%'
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/' --data-urlencode "username=$userh" --data-urlencode "password=$passwordh"
```

Let's start a `netcat` listener to check what was sent

```
netcat -l 8080
```

Received data:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 34
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=vf%26re&password=asdaf%25
```

Sending all parameters in one option will not work since password parameter gets lost triggering the server error "The username and password must be specified."

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/' --data-urlencode "username=$userh&password=$passwordh"
```

Response:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=vf%26re%26password%3Dasdaf%25
```

First command from OP with `--data` will not work either as it sends the `%` sign as is triggering a server error that "sees" and incomplete percent encoded request.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 33

username=asdasdas&password=asdaf%
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2027690/2834978).