# Download a single file from GitLab artifacts archive

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I'm running GitLab CE 11.5.0, and one of my jobs produces an artifact from which I'd like to download a single file.

Downloading the complete artifacts archive as zip file works as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/jobs.html#download-the-artifacts-archive):

```
$ export TOKEN="12345678"
$ export GITLAB_HOST="gitlab.example.com"
$ export PROJECT_ID="foo"
$ export JOB_NAME="bundle"
$ curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" \
  "https://$GITLAB_HOST/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=$JOB_NAME" -o artifacts.zip
```

The archive contents look like this:

```
$ unzip -l artifacts.zip
Archive:  artifacts.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
   262107  02-18-2019 16:17   build/ui-bundle.zip
---------                     -------
   262107                     1 file
```

Now I'd like to download only a single file from that archive, as documented [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/jobs.html#download-a-single-artifact-file-from-specific-tag-or-branch).

```
$ export FILE_PATH="build/ui-bundle.zip"
$ curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" \
  "https://$GITLAB_HOST/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/$FILE_PATH?job=$JOB_NAME"
```

But it seems that Gitlab cannot find the requested file:

```
{"error":"404 Not Found"}
```

I realize that the artifacts archive is a zip file containing just a single embedded zip file, but I'd assume that shouldn't make a difference.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gitlab's documentation should be improved. You need to urlencode the **artifact path** and the **project id**:

```
$ export TOKEN="12345678"
$ export GITLAB_HOST="gitlab.example.com"
$ export PROJECT_ID="foo"
$ export URLENCODED_PROJECT_ID="foo"
$ export JOB_NAME="bundle"
$ export FILE_PATH="build/ui-bundle.zip"
$ export URLENCODED_FILE_PATH="build%2Fui-bundle.zip"
$ curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN"\
  "https://$GITLAB_HOST/api/v4/projects/$URLENCODED_PROJECT_ID/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/$URLENCODED_FILE_PATH?job=$JOB_NAME"
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660730/2980158) has a bash implementation for urlencode function.

Answer (score 0):

If they change the route, a simple way to learn download URL is to go to the desired file and hover over the file you want to download as such:
[image: Gitlab]

At the bottom, you can see the download link the button directs you. In this case it is in the format:

https://gitlab.com/userName/projectname/-/jobs/insertjobnumberhere/artifacts/raw/Path/ToFile/ExampleProjectName.apk?inline=false