# Did I discover a bug in Telegram?

Tags: linux, bash, telegram, telegram-bot

I use a Telegram bot to incorporate weather alerts from a local weatherservice into my homeautomation system. Today I discovered a weird problem because the message containing the weather alert wasn't sent. If I try this in bash on Linux:
`output="Nationaal Hitteplan";curl "https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxxxxxx:longsecuritycode/sendMessage?chat_id=xxxxxxxxx&text=$output"`
(I removed my personal tokens in the above command of course...)
then I get a **400 Bad Request** and the message is not sent.
If I change output="Nationaal Hitteplan" to output="Nationaal hitteplan" then the message is send as it is supposed to be.
I don't see what's wrong here. The term Nationaal Hitteplan is basically a set of advisories about what to do in hot weather. It has no negative meaning associated with it but apparently Telegram detects a problem.
Does someone have a solution for this except from changing the term as described above?

Comment: Try replacing the space with %20

Comment: To expand on @xhienne's suggestion, try percent-encoding any strings you pass as URL parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Url's that contains special characters like a space should be url-encoded.

Use the following curl command to let curl let the encoding:

```
token='xxxxxxxxx:longsecuritycode';
output="Nationaal Hitteplan";
curl -G \
    --data-urlencode 'chat_id=1234567' \
    --data-urlencode "text=${output}" \
    "https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/sendMessage"
```

[How to urlencode data for curl command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command)

Comment: Thanks, that works great. It also saves on some filtering that was previously necessary.