# Links to SMB shares mount a folder and not the volume

Tags: windows, macos, powershell, hyperlink, applescript

I have some scripts to help us send links back and forth over email that are cross platform compatible. The links open the files and folders just fine. However, on OSX it mounts a folder instead of the volume. This seems to cause issues when we import files into Adobe Applications.
Example of what we send:

```
smb://fs6/CP_P/Transfer/Byron/Rocky
```

When I click that on OSX, it opens a finder window that has **"Rocky"** as the top level, not **fs6/CP_P/Transfer/**.  So if I were to drag a file from the folder into Adobe Premiere the path ends up showing **volumes/fs6/Rocky** or something that skips many of the intermediate folders.

How can I open a link or send one that has Finder showing me the whole path to the file and not mounting the folder?

Here's an example of the shell script code in the Run Shell Script action in Automator:

```
# using 'mount' command output:
FIRSTPART=$(mount | grep "$(echo $1 | cut -d '/' -f 1-3)" | sed 's/^.*@\(.*\) on.*$/\1/g')

# Glue on the rest of the path
SECONDPART=$(echo $1 | cut -d '/' -f 4-)
WHOLETHING=$FIRSTPART/$SECONDPART

# now we url encode it
# oneliner modified from http://stackoverflow.com/a/10797966
ENCODED=$(echo "$WHOLETHING" | curl -Gso /dev/null -w %{url_effective} --data-urlencode @- "" | cut -c 3- | rev | cut -c 4- | rev)
# and we need to change the %2Fs back into /s, and add the smb://

FINAL=smb://$(echo $ENCODED | sed 's/\%2F/\//g')

echo "$FINAL"
```

Then this AppleScript code in the Run AppleScript action in Automator:

```
on searchReplace(theText, SearchString, ReplaceString)
    set OldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to SearchString
    set newText to text items of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ReplaceString
    set newText to newText as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to OldDelims
    return newText
end searchReplace

on replace_chars(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
    set the item_list to every text item of this_text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
    set this_text to the item_list as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return this_text
end replace_chars

on run {input, parameters}

    set myClip to the input
    set mytext to searchReplace(myClip, "<", "")
    set mytext to searchReplace(mytext, ">.", "")
    set mytext to searchReplace(mytext, ">", "")
    set mytext to searchReplace(mytext, "smb://", "\\\\")
    set findIt to "/"
    set replaceIt to "\\"
    set mylocation to searchReplace(mytext, findIt, replaceIt)

    #return mylocation
    set MacPath to "Mac: " & input
    if input contains "vs3.local" then
        #display dialog "vs3.local present " & input
        set Mac_Path_Local to "Direct " & Mac_Path
        set the Mac_Path to replace_chars(MacPath, "//vs3.local/", "//vs3/")
    else if input contains "//vs3/" then
        #display dialog "vs3 present " & input
        set the Mac_Path_Local to "Direct " & replace_chars(MacPath, "//vs3/", "//vs3.local/")
    else
        set the Mac_Path_Local to "no .local path needed"
    end if  
    
    set WinPath to "Win: " & replace_chars(mylocation, "vs3.local", "vs3")  
    return WinPath & return & MacPath & return & Mac_Path_Local     
    
end run
```

Comment: Byron, you need to show some code before folks can really understand what you're asking and offer help. Your question will get downgraded until you show the work you've done so far.

Comment: Edited my original post to include some code. I think it's more an issue of how OSX opens SMB links, but I'm not sure.