# Use curl url data encoding with urls without querystring

Tags: curl, urlencode

I have an api server that support the urls to be in this format

```
api.add_resource(Component, '/mycustom-url/<string:text>',
             methods=['GET'])
```

I need to support using it with curl.

The string might be arabic, so we need to urlencode before sending with curl. I want to do it through the curl command directly.

In [docs](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html), I can see using -d with query string

```
curl -d "name=curl" https://example.com
```

Is there a way to use it for full urlencode or the last parameter part?

eg: I want to be able to call `curl  https://example.com/mycustom-url/عربي.`   without [url encoding](https://www.urlencoder.org/) then send the long encoded one through curl?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2027690/724039.  `curl -G --data-urlencode "name=curl" https://example.com`

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution for this issue is to put the arabic string inside "" and add space to the url

eg.

```
curl  https://example.com/mycustom-url/" عربي"
```

This way the bash will interpret the string as part of the url and concatenate the string to the url. It will be sent implicitly with url encoding and the api will receive it successfuly.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following PHP script (named: test.php):

```
<?php
echo "GET:";
var_dump($_GET);
```

Then this:

```
curl -G --data-urlencode "name=%E2%82%AC" http://localhost/test.php?name2=%E2%82%AC
```

Will produce:

```
GET:array(2) {
  ["name2"]=>
  string(3) "€"
  ["name"]=>
  string(9) "%E2%82%AC"
}
```

- You see that the `name` is not urldecoded, and that `name2` is urldecoded.
- The characters `%E2%82%AC` represent the urlencoded [`€`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm) character

Conclusion: you still need the to urlencode the string...

Comment: That's what the docs provides, I can't use querystring, the api is there n can't change it, I need to work with it as is, and it's format is /url/param. No querystring. U got the need?