# Calling API through requests Library to get access token

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, restful-authentication

I am trying to get the access token for a specific API, the curl command is given below:

```
    curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/oauth/connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=abcd' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=abc' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=us' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=a' \
--data-urlencode 'password=abc'
```

I have the following code in python:

```
url = 'https://example.com/oauth/connect/token'
body = {'client_id':'abcd', 
'client_password':'abc', 
'grant_type':'password',
'username':'us',  
'scope':'a',
'password':'abc'}
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers, verify=False)
print(response,response.content)
```

I keep receiving a `<Response [400]> b'{"error":"invalid_client"}'` error.

I believe I have tried almost everything there is out there and I am lost. Please let me know if I am missing something really simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed, that your `curl` command uses `client_secret`, while your `requests` command uses `client_password`.

For debugging such requests, I recommend free pages like https://www.toptal.com/developers/postbin/, where you can send the `curl` and the `requests` message and compare what arrived on the endpoint.

Comment: Do you mean send it as `params = body`?

Comment: Yes. Your form data is not set in the request body. It is set as URL parameters. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command for more details.

Comment: set `requests.post(url, params=body ....)` still getting the same issue.

Comment: Did you try the edited answer?

Comment: okay, I changed it to `client_secret` instead of `client_password` and it worked