# Signed url with & causing problems when performing curl request

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform

I'm creating resumable upload signed urls in google cloud and passing the link to an external API for performing some process. On examining the callbacks from the API, I can see the url actually being split into different parameters because of the & present in the google signed url.

```
callback": "https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/file-name?x-goog-"x-goog-date": "20220303T233221Z",
"x-goog-expires": "3600",
"callback_method": "put",
"x-goog-algorithm": "GOOG4-RSA-SHA256",
"x-goog-credential": "****",
"x-goog-signedheaders": "host"
```

The signed url looks like

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/file-name?x-goog-signature=4398348934893498fjksdfjksdjk&x-goog-algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&x-goog-credential=bucket40project.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F2003%2Fus-west1%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&x-goog-date=202201Z&x-goog-expires=3600&x-goog-signedheaders=host
```

and the curl request to the API looks like

```
curl --request POST
-url 'website.com?callback=<the above url>"
--header 
--data
```

Any input would be really appreciated. I tried including an `\` before the `&` or enclosing it within quotes, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Using `urllib.parse.quote(url)` in python did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command).

You need to url-encode the previous url

```
curl --request POST \
    --data-urlencode "callback=<the above url>" \
    website.com
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me unfortunately.