# I need to pass json-data to API with special characters

Tags: json, zsh, special-characters

I am trying to push some data to my Tiddlywiki via API so I can create a new tiddler.
I can pass almost all the data, but if the value "text" has spaces inside it breaks the curl command trying to pass multiple URLs.

This is the actual command:

```
curl -X PUT -i "http://192.168.1.166:8080/recipes/default/tiddlers/$title" -H "X-Requested-With: TiddlyWiki" --data $(jq -nc --arg tags "$tag" --arg text "'${content}'" '{ $tags, $text }')
```

I tried at first using `$variables`, inside brackets, even inside multiple `"'"$var"'"` following others questions here. But most of them quickly recommended using jq so I gave it a try.

I learned how to create some keys with the bash¡s variables contents, and If I pipe all of this I can get it to work only if I replace spaces with other characters...I tried %20 or scraping the space </kbd> with sed without success. (%20 is replaced literally so not helpful)

Any recommendations at all, I will follow any other path you could bring to it.

EDIT:
I tried using `--data-urlencode "text=${var}"` but it wasn't filled, only variable expanded was the title. The others didn't show at all.

API'S INFO:
https://tiddlywiki.com/static/WebServer%2520API%253A%2520Put%2520Tiddler.html

I forgot to mention that I am using zsh shell...

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly I believe you are wanting to "url encode" your json string. Some good options here: [How to urlencode data for curl command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried using --data-urlencode with $vars and json strings piping jq but didnt succes.

Comment: `--arg text "'${content}'"` looks like a double quoting error but we can't know what the API expects.

Comment: I tried "${content}" too. I tried with single quotes thinking that it would expand the variable maintaning the spaces in the meantime. My actual problem is to get CURL to understand that $content is a block of text, not separated identities. Sorry for my English, I feel limited to express my difficulties.

Comment: Added some info to the initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote the output of the command substitution: `--data "$(jq ...)"`. Without this, curl thinks the words after the first one are individual URLs to connect to. You should also remove the single quotes from `--arg text "'${content}'"`, otherwise they'll be added to the text itself.

Comment: This was the solution for me. Thanks a lot for your time.