# PromQL and node-exporter: Peak memory consumption on a server during last minute

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

I try to obtain peak memory consumption on a server during last minute using PromQL and node-exporter metrics. When I use prometheus API like this:

```
curl -X POST -g 'http://epgt012:9070/api/v1/query?query=max_over_time(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="epgp003:9401"}-(node_memory_MemFree_bytes{instance="epgp003:9401"}+node_memory_Cached_bytes{instance="epgp003:9401"}+node_memory_Buffers_bytes{instance="epgp003:9401"})[1m])'
```

I get this error: `{"status":"error","errorType":"bad_data","error":"invalid parameter \"query\": 1:143: parse error: unexpected identifier \"node_memory_Cached_bytes\""}`

I should note that when I run `curl -X POST -g 'http://epgt012:9070/api/v1/query?query=node_memory_Cached_bytes{instance="epgp003:9401"}'` I get proper response.

Once I run that query inside prometheus UI:

```
max_over_time(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="epgp003:9401"}-(node_memory_MemFree_bytes{instance="epgp003:9401"}+node_memory_Cached_bytes{instance="epgp003:9401"}+node_memory_Buffers_bytes{instance="epgp003:9401"})[1m])
```

I get this error: `Error executing query: invalid parameter "query": 1:268: parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors`.

So it looks like I have two problems here. At the end I need to obtain results using `curl`. I tried all kind of different variations of the above, but couldn't get a working query.

Additionally it also would be nice to get peak memory consumption on a server between point in time - `start` and `end` (and not during last minute) using `query_range` api call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Your original problem with curl

`+` has a special meaning in URLs, and need to be encoded when used there.

Your parameter `query` is expected to be

```
max_over_time(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance%3D"epgp003%3A9401"}-(node_memory_MemFree_bytes{instance%3D"epgp003%3A9401"}%2Bnode_memory_Cached_bytes{instance%3D"epgp003%3A9401"}%2Bnode_memory_Buffers_bytes{instance%3D"epgp003%3A9401"})[1m])
```

You can achieve this by manually encoding your parameters, or using something like [`--data-urlencode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2027690/21363224)

##### Your promQL problem

PromQL doesn't allow to apply range selector straight to the complex selector, it is only applicable to the vector selector. But you can use [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) syntax. In this case you query will look like this:

```
max_over_time((node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="epgp003:9401"}-(node_memory_MemFree_bytes{instance="epgp003:9401"}+node_memory_Cached_bytes{instance="epgp003:9401"}+node_memory_Buffers_bytes{instance="epgp003:9401"}))[1m:])
```

Comment: Thank you @markalex! Maybe you also have an answer to the [CPU usage related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76721902/1876484)?

Comment: how will this query look like if instead of last minute `[1m:]` I have a `query_range` with a `start` an `end` and a `step`? Thank you!

Comment: @user1876484, sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you want. query_range parameters has nothing to do with range selector in query.

Comment: I mean, that now I need to get peak memory consumption on a server between point in time - `start` and `end` (and not as before - during last minute). Thank you!

Comment: @user1876484, then you'll need to calculate difference between end and start, convert it to prometheus notation and supply it as a range selector (still using `query` endpoint). Or use `query_range` and select maximum manually.